# Fortnightly topic challenge #1: Space

Tags: discussion, challenge

Yesterday I wrote up [a post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/should-we-have-weekly-topic-challenges) asking if people would like weekly - now fortnightly topic challenges. The answer from the community was a resounding yes.

So today will be the first one. As per some of the suggestions, I'm going to start with tags that have seen a decent amount of activity but still aren't commonly used. For the next two weeks, the tag will be [space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space). Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, I'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat). Let's build some new worlds!

Comment: If we post questions as part of this should we put an answer here with a link to the questions?  Or is that superfluous?

Comment: A search on the Space tag will find them all so I don't think it's needed?

Comment: Should there be a "topic challenge" tag?

Comment: Would "Fortnightly" be less ambiguous than "Biweekly"? When I see biweekly my brain says both "twice a week" and "every second week".

Comment: @VilleNiemi I think [tag:challenge] covers it.

Comment: @trichoplax "Fortnightly" works.

Comment: I think that a [tag:challenge] tag to indicate which questions are part of the challenge are unnecessary, like @Tim already pointed out. [tag:space] should be enough, I think.

Comment: Recommendation: after the challenge is over, post the "winners" in an answer [like this one](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/q/621), please :)

Comment: @Shokhet That's what I'm planning to do.

Comment: Great :) ....I thought that it might be useful as a template for our challenges.

Comment: Boo, so no actual score? ... (Grouchy) I suppose it's better that way...

Comment: @SerbanTanasa Care to sort through about 100 answers? :-) There were quite a few. It took me about an hour or two to post the answer.

Comment: I take it the SQL didn't help? Pity. Appreciate the effort you put into it, of course!

Comment: @SerbanTanasa Nah, didn't help with the tallying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During this challenge, there were 26 [space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space) questions:

- [How small could an Earth-like planet be while still realistically being able to sustain human life?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9900/how-small-could-an-earth-like-planet-be-while-still-realistically-being-able-to)
- [Must all planets have a solid/liquid core?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9922/must-all-planets-have-a-solid-liquid-core)
- [In Space, how can they hear me scream?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9923/in-space-how-can-they-hear-me-scream)
- [Is there a theoretical maximum size for rocky planets?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9948/is-there-a-theoretical-maximum-size-for-rocky-planets)
- [How long before we're **stuck** on Earth due to Space Debris? (Kessler syndrome)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9967/how-long-before-were-stuck-on-earth-due-to-space-debris)
- [How could we do steampunk space travel, with minimal magic?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9980/how-could-we-do-steampunk-space-travel-with-minimal-magic)
- [How big can a space empire get?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10004/how-big-can-a-space-empire-get)
- [What modifications would be needed to allow humans to survive in space with limited protective gear?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10082/what-modifications-would-be-needed-to-allow-humans-to-survive-in-space-with-limi)
- [What if the speed of light were 100 times higher?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10126/what-if-the-speed-of-light-were-100-times-higher)
- [How can I destroy a gas giant planet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10150/how-can-i-destroy-a-gas-giant-planet)
- [How far could life develop inside a black hole before it explodes?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10153/how-far-could-life-develop-inside-a-black-hole-before-it-explodes)
- [Where should I place my city in space?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10166/where-should-i-place-my-city-in-space)
- [Conditions needed for a Fractured Moon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10186/conditions-needed-for-a-fractured-moon)
- [The new Space Race - Racing!](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10214/the-new-space-race-racing)
- [What sports could safely and easily be played in space?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10276/what-sports-could-safely-and-easily-be-played-in-space)
- [Are islands flying in space possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/are-islands-flying-in-space-possible)
- [Space, the final frontier … to defend](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10307/space-the-final-frontier-to-defend)
- [Prison in space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10332/prison-in-space)
- [Expanding your empire's space from the inside — can it be useful?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10377/expanding-your-empires-space-from-the-inside-can-it-be-useful)
- [Information Exchange In Space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10428/information-exchange-in-space)
- [Can a planet with 2/3 Orbital eccentricity sustain life?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10434/can-a-planet-with-2-3-orbital-eccentricity-sustain-life)
- [A planet made of trash?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10492/a-planet-made-of-trash)
- [How would I transport an atmosphere?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10502/how-would-i-transport-an-atmosphere)
- [Interstellar commerce: how easy would it be to find sources of potable water in space?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10560/interstellar-commerce-how-easy-would-it-be-to-find-sources-of-potable-water-in)
- [Interstellar commerce: how accessible are oxygen sources in space?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10563/interstellar-commerce-how-accessible-are-oxygen-sources-in-space)
- [Interstellar internet use cases, or "What if the internet was mail-order?"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10601/interstellar-internet-use-cases-or-what-if-the-internet-was-mail-order)

Many, many people participated. Here they are:

**Askers:**

[image: akaddoura]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Answerers:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### [Tag Usage Graph](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300992/tag-usage-over-time?TagName=space#graph)

Comment: Hmmm … I wonder why my image doesn't show up in my entry (at least not for me). Not that it really matters, but it's somehow strange, especially since I seem to be the only one with that problem.