# Fortnightly topic challenge #3: Creature Design

Tags: discussion, challenge

**Today begins our Third topic challenge!**

Topic:  [creature-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design)

Dates:  9 March - 22 March

Proposed by:

[image]

> We've only had a handful of creature-design questions, but they've
>   been a joy to ask, answer, comment on, discuss; the works! I can't
>   help but love the idea of a frenzy of questions asking for creature
>   designs - they truly are challenging, interesting and occasionally
>   just a fun question.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat. Let the games begin.

---

**Previous Challenges**

[Fortnightly topic challenge #2: Flora](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-flora)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #1: Space](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-space)

Answer (score 5):

**In total we had 19 [creature-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design) questions over the last two weeks.**

[Asymmetrical animals](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11667/asymmetrical-animals)

[Multigeneration ship pet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11721/multigeneration-ship-pet)

[Earth, Wind, and Water: Naturally Navigating All Three](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11676/earth-wind-and-water-naturally-navigating-all-three)

[Intelligent Cats With A Serious Attitude Problem](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11637/intelligent-cats-with-a-serious-attitude-problem)

[Can telepathy and telekinesis exist in biological creatures?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12294/can-telepathy-and-telekinesis-exist-in-biological-creatures)

[How to Strengthen Bones](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11648/how-to-strengthen-bones)

[Most effective way to camouflage a visible physical connection on a creature that uses part of its body as a lure?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12270/most-effective-way-to-camouflage-a-visible-physical-connection-on-a-creature-tha)

[A Human Hunter with Sonic Powers?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11610/a-creature-with-sonic-powers)

[Sharks with frickin' lasers!](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11622/sharks-with-frickin-lasers)

[We saw that in orbit....wait, how did it get down here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11679/we-saw-that-in-orbit-wait-how-did-it-get-down-here)

[Evolutionary Explanations for Dragon Firebreathing: Interesting uses of indigestion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11650/evolutionary-explanations-for-dragon-firebreathing-interesting-uses-of-indigest)

[Could insects evolve that could create a hole in a stone wall within a day?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11992/could-insects-evolve-that-could-create-a-hole-in-a-stone-wall-within-a-day)

[Creature with a non-centralized brain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/creature-with-a-non-centralized-brain)

[Evolution of a predatory antlered cat?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11817/evolution-of-a-predatory-antlered-cat)

[Breathing lightning](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11767/breathing-lightning)

[Animals for weightlessness](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11970/animals-for-weightlessness)

[Death to humans by deadly monsters](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/death-to-humans-by-deadly-monsters)

[Creatures that can "Displace" themselves](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12521/creatures-that-can-displace-themselves)

[How to insure my Hulk's survival](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/how-to-insure-my-hulks-survival)

---

**Questions were asked by:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**We also had a total of 99 answers...for 5.2 answers per question.**

(I'm not going to post all the answers/answerers...)

### [Tag Usage Graph](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300992/tag-usage-over-time?TagName=creature-design#graph)

Comment: That must have taken a lot of patience to put together. You're a saint!

Answer (score 1):

For the impatient and/or hopelessly competitive minded:

[**Posts By Votes And Views for Tag in Timerange**](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/292082/posts-by-votes-and-views-for-tag-in-timerange)

<sup>Note that data.stackexchange is usually a little bit behind the live-servers so some Questions/Votes might not show up until a few days later.</sup>