# Fortnightly topic challenge #4: Magic

Tags: discussion, challenge

**Today begins our fourth topic challenge!**

Topic:  [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic)

Dates:  23 March - 5 April

Proposed by:

[image]

> When I joined Worldbuilding, I told myself that I would only answer
>   science-based questions. I'd stay away from magic-based or
>   fantasy-based questions. I've done a decent job of it, but I've seen
>   lots of brilliant questions asked about magic. It seems to bring out a
>   lot of creativity in people.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat. Let the games begin.

---

**Previous Challenges**

[Fortnightly topic challenge #3: Creature Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/fortnightly-topic-challenge-3-creature-design?cb=1)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #2: Flora](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-flora)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #1: Space](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-space)

Comment: Man, I better get started on some questions!

Comment: @HDE226868 hahahaha.  No math allowed.

Comment: I shall find a way!

Comment: @James the mathematical world summons you. Seriously, we can involve meth anywhere

Comment: @ArtOfCode Ill go ahead and assume you meant math.  Hahahahahaha

Comment: @James oh. Oh. Whoops. You saw nothing.

Comment: I forsee this challenge being a difficult one. I can't think of many magical questions that can't be answered by "pfft, it's magic".

Comment: Topic *challenge* ;)

Comment: What about [Mathmagic](https://youtu.be/U_ZHsk0-eF0)?

Comment: Pick me please!

Answer (score 2):

We just had our most popular challenge until now with 36 [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) questions including 2 closed questions

1. [How to cure a phobia with magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12600/how-to-cure-a-phobia-with-magic)
2. [How can I imprison a wizard who can walk through walls?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12634/how-can-i-imprison-a-wizard-who-can-walk-through-walls)
3. [Uses for Limited Human Flight in Medieval Setting](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12772/uses-for-limited-human-flight-in-medieval-setting)
4. [Magical April Fools prank](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12774/magical-april-fools-prank)
   (close)
5. [How to defeat a nature Mage?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12801/how-to-defeat-a-nature-mage)
6. [Non-logical Magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12853/non-logical-magic)
7. [Magic that alters living cells - How to efficiently battle with it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12859/magic-that-alters-living-cells-how-to-efficiently-battle-with-it)
8. [How can fae rescue one of their number from an iron cage?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12901/how-can-fae-rescue-one-of-their-number-from-an-iron-cage)
9. [How to escape a horde of worms using magic with minimal injury?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12912/how-to-escape-a-horde-of-worms-using-magic-with-minimal-injury)
10. [How Do I Draw the Elves into the War?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12923/how-do-i-draw-the-elves-into-the-war)
11. [Magically knock someone down and pin them using Science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12925/magically-knock-someone-down-and-pin-them-using-science)
12. [How to minimize the threat of guns in present day magic fantasy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/how-to-minimize-the-threat-of-guns-in-present-day-magic-fantasy)
13. [How could flying soldiers influence medieval battle tactics?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12985/how-could-flying-soldiers-influence-medieval-battle-tactics)
14. [A Most Subtle Magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12990/a-most-subtle-magic)
15. [How to Escape an Impossible Situation Using Minimal Magic?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13042/how-to-escape-an-impossible-situation-using-minimal-magic)
16. [Limited Fate sensing powers to give protagonist of miyazaki style story](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/limited-fate-sensing-powers-to-give-protagonist-of-miyazaki-style-story)
17. [Use of Liquid Potential Energy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13114/use-of-liquid-potential-energy)
18. [Magivore - designing a magic 'eater'](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13129/magivore-designing-a-magic-eater)
19. [Sympathy: Give me the chills!](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13141/sympathy-give-me-the-chills)
20. [Designing a battery to store light](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13145/designing-a-battery-to-store-light)
21. [What might be dangers of connecting your own soul to a stronger soul?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13149/magic-what-might-be-dangers-of-connecting-your-own-soul-to-a-stronger-soul)
22. [How would an intelligent planet develop the ability to bend space-time?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13212/how-would-an-intelligent-planet-develop-the-ability-to-bend-space-time)
23. [Can you have magic that doesn't have rules?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13234/can-you-have-magic-that-doesnt-have-rules)
24. [Magic as Luck Control](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13285/magic-as-luck-control)
25. [Magic on an atomic level?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13326/magic-on-an-atomic-level)
26. [Will my magic system decrease its credibility?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13339/will-my-magic-system-decrease-its-credibility)
     (closed)
27. [If magic is real, can it be true that rational scientific thought should exclude it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13364/if-magic-is-real-can-it-be-true-that-rational-scientific-thought-should-exclude)
28. [Would science emerge in a world with magic?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13384/would-science-emerge-in-a-world-with-magic)
29. [Magic that alters living cells - Growing cities out of trees?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13393/magic-that-alters-living-cells-growing-cities-out-of-trees)
30. [Development of society with random encounters](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13638/development-of-society-with-random-encounters)
31. [The Magical British Government: At War](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13670/the-magical-british-government-at-war)

**Questions asked by:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

We add 207 answers during the challenge. This is an average of 6,68 answers per question, including the closed questions.

### [Tag Usage Graph](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300992/tag-usage-over-time?TagName=magic#graph)

Good job everyone!

Comment: Thanks Vincent, been swamped, never would have gotten to this today.