# Fortnightly topic challenge #5 : City Design

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our fifth topic challenge!

Topic:  [city-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city-design)

Dates: 6 April - 19 April

Proposed by:

[image]

> I've enjoyed these questions. I can see these sort of questions being asked:
>
> -Given x environment (available resources etc) what would a city look like
>
> -Given x technologies...
>
> I am sure there are more.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat. Let's build some cities.

---

**Propose new topics here:** [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

**Previous Challenges**

[Fortnightly topic challenge #4: Magic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/fortnightly-topic-challenge-4-magic)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #3: Creature Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/fortnightly-topic-challenge-3-creature-design?cb=1)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #2: Flora](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-flora)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #1: Space](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-space)

Comment: As an Urban Planner both in the states and in the middle east, I'm looking forward to the questions.  At the risk of being a "me too" comment, I'd like to say I'm looking forward to these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic challenge generated 21 questions and 134 answers (no I didn't count them wrong... we really did get that many), for an average of 6.38 answers per question.

### Questions by date asked

1. [Cities in the trees](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13768/cities-in-the-trees?s=21|0.0000)
2. [Would it be possible for a city floating on water to exist?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13774/would-it-be-possible-for-a-city-floating-on-water-to-exist?s=20|0.0000)
3. [How would cities be designed that were threatened by dragons?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13794/how-would-cities-be-designed-that-were-threatened-by-dragons?s=19|0.0000)
4. [Urban cohabitation of dragons and non-dragons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13810/urban-cohabitation-of-dragons-and-non-dragons?s=18|0.0000)
5. [How to build a city surrounded by giant spiders?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13819/how-to-build-a-city-surrounded-by-giant-spiders?s=17|0.0000)
6. [A modern Manhattan city planner in New Amsterdam](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13892/a-modern-manhattan-city-planner-in-new-amsterdam?s=16|0.0000)
7. [City Design: Freefall](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/city-design-freefall?s=15|0.0000)
8. [Rapid Planetary Colonization: How to Build a City, Fast](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13967/rapid-planetary-colonization-how-to-build-a-city-fast?s=14|0.0000)
9. [How would antigravity change the design of cities and buildings?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13968/how-would-antigravity-change-the-design-of-cities-and-buildings?s=13|0.0000)
10. [Growing a city (literally)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14089/growing-a-city-literally?s=12|0.0000)
11. [Designing cities inside a hollowed-out asteroids](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14110/designing-cities-inside-a-hollowed-out-asteroids?s=11|0.0000)
12. [How to build a tsunami proof island city?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14167/how-to-build-a-tsunami-proof-island-city?s=10|0.0000)
13. [Designing a city around a giant tree?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14244/designing-a-city-around-a-giant-tree?s=9|0.0000)
14. [Can I make a movable medieval city?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/can-i-make-a-movable-medieval-city?s=8|0.0000)
15. [A city of Sand…stone](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14435/a-city-of-sand-stone?s=7|0.0000)
16. [Size of a medieval/fantasy trading port](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14456/size-of-a-medieval-fantasy-trading-port?s=6|0.0000)
17. [How would cities be built on large ruins?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14535/how-would-cities-be-built-on-large-ruins?s=5|0.0000)
18. [What power generation method is the best to sustain a hovering city?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14558/what-power-generation-method-is-the-best-to-sustain-a-hovering-city?s=4|0.0000)
19. [Just how unrealistic is a hovering city?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14581/just-how-unrealistic-is-a-hovering-city?s=3|0.0000)
20. [City in the wake of the Yggdrasil: Engineering Considerations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/city-in-the-wake-of-the-yggdrasil-engineering-considerations?s=2|0.0000)
21. [What are the design considerations for my underwater settlement?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14686/what-are-the-design-considerations-for-my-underwater-settlement?s=1|0.0000)

### Questions asked by

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### [Tag Usage Graph](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300992/tag-usage-over-time?TagName=city-design#graph)

Good job!

Answer (score 0):

These are promoted as "challenges", implying some kind of judging and competition.

> a call or summons to engage in any contest, as of skill, strength, etc.

Perhaps *exhibit*, *expose*, *showcase*, or *feature* would be better terms?

Comment: You should add this to one of the main posts (e.g. http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/should-we-have-weekly-topic-challenges?rq=1), not a specific one.