# Fortnightly topic challenge #6: Evolution

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our sixth topic challenge!

Topic:  [evolution](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evolution)

Dates: 19 April - 3 May

Proposed by:

[image]

> Because it impacts almost all aspects of a world, from the mundane to the central, yet is often given lip service by authors.
>
> Just how did my creatures evolve to have blue skin? How could several intelligent species co-evolve in the same environment without outcompeting each other?
>
> These types of questions often permeate a story to varying levels, and definitely shape the environment that the story takes place in.
>   I've enjoyed these questions. I can see these sort of questions being asked:

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat. Let's build some cities.

---

**Propose new topics here:** [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

**Previous Challenges**

[Fortnightly topic challenge #5 : City Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/fortnightly-topic-challenge-5-city-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #4: Magic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/fortnightly-topic-challenge-4-magic)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #3: Creature Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/fortnightly-topic-challenge-3-creature-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #2: Flora](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-flora)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #1: Space](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-space)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This topic challenge generated 26 questions and 112 answers, for an average of 4.3 answers per question.

### Questions by date asked

1. [What needs to be different in order for a parthenogenetically reproducing species to evolve sentience?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15530/what-needs-to-be-different-in-order-for-a-parthenogenetically-reproducing-specie)
2. [Red giant Habitable zone](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/red-giant-habitable-zone)
3. [Macroscopic life in the Dead Sea?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15432/macroscopic-life-in-the-dead-sea)
4. [Can a creature evolve to preserve its own environment?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15343/can-a-creature-evolve-to-preserve-its-own-environment)
5. [Sea creature moving via rotational motions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15278/sea-creature-moving-via-rotational-motions)
6. [How would a plant evolve to germinate inside a person (or other animal)?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15263/how-would-a-plant-evolve-to-germinate-inside-a-person-or-other-animal)
7. [What form of life was brought to earth by aliens?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15231/what-form-of-life-was-brought-to-earth-by-aliens)
8. [Interlocking, ultra-high forest, is it possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15216/interlocking-ultra-high-forest-is-it-possible)
9. [How could something like a Gargoyle evolve?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15215/how-could-something-like-a-gargoyle-evolve)
10. [Is bio-luminescence possible in aquatic mammals?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/is-bio-luminescence-possible-in-aquatic-mammals)
11. [Evolving another pair of limbs?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15156/evolving-another-pair-of-limbs)
12. [Survival without emotion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15101/survival-without-emotion)
13. [How would a Reflecting-Oven-Jay Evolve?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15061/how-would-a-reflecting-oven-jay-evolve)
14. [People of the Sea- Living on a Migratory Fleet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15056/people-of-the-sea-living-on-a-migratory-fleet)
15. [How far in the future would a modern human need to go before they were functionally a different species than people of the time?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14962/how-far-in-the-future-would-a-modern-human-need-to-go-before-they-were-functiona)
16. [Food economy of pre-civilization carnivorous humanoids](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14919/food-economy-of-pre-civilization-carnivorous-humanoids)
17. [Evolution of a creature that uses light as a weapon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14877/evolution-of-a-creature-that-uses-light-as-a-weapon)
18. [Could an animal species evolve to use electricity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14861/could-an-animal-species-evolve-to-use-electricity)
19. [Is my humanoid creature too far out there?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14822/is-my-humanoid-creature-too-far-out-there)
20. [What are the conditions in which a creature would evolve more than one brain?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14807/what-are-the-conditions-in-which-a-creature-would-evolve-more-than-one-brain)
21. [Evolution of a naturally invisible prey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14790/evolution-of-a-naturally-invisible-prey)
22. [Evolution of a naturally invisible predator](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14789/evolution-of-a-naturally-invisible-predator)
23. [Animal life on a planet orbiting a red dwarf](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14788/animal-life-on-a-planet-orbiting-a-red-dwarf)
24. [How can people naturally become smaller?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14743/how-can-people-naturally-become-smaller)
25. [What would be the evolutionary adaptations of a subterranean fantasy race?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14741/what-would-be-the-evolutionary-adaptations-of-a-subterranean-fantasy-race)
26. [How could animals evolve like they do in Pokémon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/14738/how-could-animals-evolve-like-they-do-in-pok%C3%A9mon)

### Questions asked by

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### [Tag Usage Graph](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300992/tag-usage-over-time?TagName=evolution#graph)

Comment: Thank you, James!