# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #7: Economy

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our seventh topic challenge!

Topic:  [economy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy)

Dates: 4 May - 17 May

Proposed by:

[image]

> Because too often fictional worlds have no visible economic activity.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat. Let's build some cities.

---

**Propose new topics here:** [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

**Previous Challenges**

[Fortnightly topic challenge #6: Evolution](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/fortnightly-topic-challenge-6-evolution)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #5 : City Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/fortnightly-topic-challenge-5-city-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #4: Magic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/fortnightly-topic-challenge-4-magic)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #3: Creature Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/fortnightly-topic-challenge-3-creature-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #2: Flora](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-flora)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #1: Space](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-space)

Comment: Since these "previous challenges" lists are starting to become slightly long, maybe in the future we should just point to the "previous topics" list in the topic suggestion question instead? That will also keep the "linked" sidebar more clean.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Agreed

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Good idea.

Comment: I just realized, this challenge is over. Do we need someone to compile the results and start the next challenge?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - if you can compile the results, I'll write up the next challenge.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I had some trouble connecting to the Internet this weekend, but it's up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a total of 17 questions asked with this tag this time around, with a total of *106* answers.

## Questions

1- [Measuring the economic power of a country over time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/15675/measuring-the-economic-power-of-a-country-over-time) 
2- [A Room for Heroes on the Run](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16736/a-room-for-heroes-on-the-run) 
3- [Favor based economy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16737/favor-based-economy) 
4- [Galactic Wishes - Economy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16761/galactic-wishes-economy) 
5- [The deep space mining dilemma](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16794/the-deep-space-mining-dilemma) 
6- [What are the necessary professions of an advanced society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16802/what-are-the-necessary-professions-of-an-advanced-society) 
7- [Can humans interact meaningfully with the economy when robots are better at everything?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16807/can-humans-interact-meaningfully-with-the-economy-when-robots-are-better-at-ever) 
8- [How would a lawless city function economically?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16888/how-would-a-lawless-city-function-economically) 
9- [Would glass bullets be feasible in a hypothetical world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16938/would-glass-bullets-be-feasible-in-a-hypothetical-world) 
10- [Economies of Scale](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16982/economies-of-scale) 
11- [In a truly (human) free market society, how would slavery be prevented?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17048/in-a-truly-human-free-market-society-how-would-slavery-be-prevented) 
12- [Single Resource Cities - Economy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17077/single-resource-cities-economy) 
13- [FTL travel is impossible. How is interstellar trade possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17244/ftl-travel-is-impossible-how-is-interstellar-trade-possible) 
14- [Economic Effects of 'The Rift'](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17252/economic-effects-of-the-rift) 
15- [Is mining the riverbed in a Venice-like canal city for metal ore feasible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17327/is-mining-the-riverbed-in-a-venice-like-canal-city-for-metal-ore-feasible) 
16- [Consequences of a Dragon's Hoard](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17343/consequences-of-a-dragons-hoard) 
17- [Humans moved to different planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17368/humans-moved-to-different-planets)

## Asked By

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]