# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #8: Apocalypse

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our eighth topic challenge!

Topic:  [apocalypse](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apocalypse)

Dates: 24 May - 7 June

Proposed by:

[image]

> Because for a site about building worlds we seem to spend a lot of time destroying them!
>
> (And because we might get more questions about [ragnarok](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ragnarok))

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat. Let's destroy some things.

---

**Propose new topics here:** [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

**Previous Challenges**

[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #7: Economy](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/fortnightly-topic-challenge-7-economy)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #6: Evolution](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/fortnightly-topic-challenge-6-evolution)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #5 : City Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/fortnightly-topic-challenge-5-city-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #4: Magic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/fortnightly-topic-challenge-4-magic)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #3: Creature Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/fortnightly-topic-challenge-3-creature-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #2: Flora](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-flora)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #1: Space](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-space)

Comment: Thank you, ArtOfCode!

Comment: @HDE226868 Noticed the featured post was still the old one... Haven't done the results of the last one - DaaahWhoosh might be doing it.

Comment: Yep, I did. I can do this one, too, if the need arises.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Been swamped.

Comment: Lets wrap this one up and start the next one!

Comment: @Aify you caught me in the act. Fancy writing up the results for this one while I write up the next one?

Comment: @ArtOfCode Ive just finished writing up the next one ._.

Comment: @Aify fair enough then. I'll do the results; post yours and flag for mod attention to get it retagged.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Done, and done. I'll go clean up the topic subjects post.

Comment: @Aify If there's a used topic there, you can flag that too (custom flag) for deletion.

Comment: @ArtOfCode OK, and I'm just updating the actual post for it to include q9 and move q8 down to previous topics.

Comment: @Aify Nice one, thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This challenge generated 24 questions and 118 answers, for an average of 4.92 answers per post. Good going!

<sup>Yes, this results post has a different format I"m trialling. If you don"t like it, shout at me.</sup>

**Questions**

1. [Thunder Clap Armageddon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18032/thunder-clap-armageddon?s=24|0.0000)

[image]

2. [Escaping a dying planet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17862/escaping-a-dying-planet?s=23|0.0000)

[image]

3. [Surviving the apocalyspe](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17898/surviving-the-apocalyspe?s=22|0.0000)

[image]

4. [What would happen to an urban fantasy Earth hit with a supernatural, planet-sized EMP?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17919/what-would-happen-to-an-urban-fantasy-earth-hit-with-a-supernatural-planet-size?s=21|0.00007)

[image]

5. [Is there a scientifically plausible way to wipe out power & communications in an urban-fantasy Earth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17984/is-there-a-scientifically-plausible-way-to-wipe-out-power-communications-in-an?s=20|0.0000)

[image]

6. [Size of the volcano that ends the world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18037/size-of-the-volcano-that-ends-the-world?s=19|0.0000)

[image]

7. [What could cause a predictable apocalypse?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18228/what-could-cause-a-predictable-apocalypse?s=18|0.0000)

[image]

8. [Short Term Effects of Orbital Decay](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18251/short-term-effects-of-orbital-decay?s=17|0.0000)

[image]

9. [If the sun were to go supernova, how long would Earth have before it was consumed?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18269/if-the-sun-were-to-go-supernova-how-long-would-earth-have-before-it-was-consume?s=16|0.0000)

[image]

10. [How many people are required for a healthy re-population of the Earth (Post-Apocalypse)?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18275/how-many-people-are-required-for-a-healthy-re-population-of-the-earth-post-apoc?s=15|0.0000)

[image]

11. [Building Noah's Ark](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18303/building-noahs-ark?s=14|0.0000)

[image]

12. [What if the atmospheric pressure suddenly would start decreasing slowly?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18344/what-if-the-atmospheric-pressure-suddenly-would-start-decreasing-slowly?s=13|0.0000)

[image]

13. [What single element could destroy the world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18414/what-single-element-could-destroy-the-world?s=12|0.0000)

[image]

14. [What if the earth was physically split in half?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18432/what-if-the-earth-was-physically-split-in-half?s=11|0.0000)

[image]

15. [What if the earth was turned physically inside out?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18434/what-if-the-earth-was-turned-physically-inside-out?s=10|0.0000)

[image]

16. [Aliens put us on the moon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18440/aliens-put-us-on-the-moon?s=9|0.0000)

[image]

17. [Aliens steal our trees](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18445/aliens-steal-our-trees?s=8|0.0000)

[image]

18. [Signs of a realistic Ragnarök](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18459/signs-of-a-realistic-ragnar%c3%b6k?s=7|0.0000)

[image]

19. [What if all explosives existing on earth suddenly get transported to one place and then blow up?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18473/what-if-all-explosives-existing-on-earth-suddenly-get-transported-to-one-place-a?s=6|0.0000)

[image]

20. [Changing Earth's rotation rate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18530/changing-earths-rotation-rate?s=5|0.0000)

[image]

21. [Could the Earth be flooded?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18549/could-the-earth-be-flooded?s=4|0.0000)

[image]

22. **[The Benign Apocalypse](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18556/the-benign-apocalypse?s=3|0.0000)**

**Congratulations:** this post was the most popular during the challenge.

[image]

23. [What would the effects be on a earth-like planet if the magnetic field was much stronger](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18557/what-would-the-effects-be-on-a-earth-like-planet-if-the-magnetic-field-was-much?s=2|0.0000)

[image]

24. [Laugh til you drop](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18601/laugh-til-you-drop?s=1|0.0000)

[image]