# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #9: Map-Making

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our ninth topic challenge!

Topic:  [map-making](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-making)

Dates: 8 June - 21 June

Proposed by:

[image]

> Maps add extra realism to a story and can set the stage well. They make a world come alive. Just look at Tolkien's maps - Middle-Earth seems close enough to touch!

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat. Let's make some maps!

---

**Propose new topics here:** [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

**Previous Challenges**

[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #8: Apocalypse](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/fortnightly-topic-challenge-8-apocalypse)

[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #7: Economy](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/fortnightly-topic-challenge-7-economy)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #6: Evolution](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/fortnightly-topic-challenge-6-evolution)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #5 : City Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/fortnightly-topic-challenge-5-city-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #4: Magic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/fortnightly-topic-challenge-4-magic)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #3: Creature Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/fortnightly-topic-challenge-3-creature-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #2: Flora](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-flora)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #1: Space](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-space)

Comment: Awww. Now I feel compelled to write up a question. . .

Comment: @HDE226868 As well you should! This **is** your topic!

Comment: [Done!](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/how-can-i-indicate-a-third-dimension-on-a-map-of-outer-space)

Comment: A note to whoever writes the results of this (and whoever writes the next challenge) - if you go [here](http://jenkinsstuff.bl.ee/challenge), it'll do all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This challenge generated 9 questions and 85 answers, for an average of 9.44 answers per question.

### Questions

1. [How can I indicate a third dimension on a map of outer space?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/how-can-i-indicate-a-third-dimension-on-a-map-of-outer-space)

[image]

2. [How to go about creating an "inaccurate" map?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18730/how-to-go-about-creating-an-inaccurate-map)

[image]

3. [Encrypting maps](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18736/encrypting-maps)

[image]

4. [How could bird people map the air?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18926/how-could-bird-people-map-the-air)

[image]

5. [Making the Marauder's Map: Can I make a map that changes?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18938/making-the-marauders-map-can-i-make-a-map-that-changes)

[image]

6. [How would you create a map based upon scent (or other senses)?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18957/how-would-you-create-a-map-based-upon-scent-or-other-senses)

[image]

7. [Graphically represent (map) multiple spatial dimentions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19107/graphically-represent-map-multiple-spatial-dimentions)

[image]

8. [Mapping a fantasy/horror building where rooms overlap](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19301/mapping-a-fantasy-horror-building-where-rooms-overlap)

[image]

9. [How to navigate without magnetism?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19332/how-to-navigate-without-magnetism)

[image]

Comment: This was a toughy, but there's some great questions there!