# Fortnightly topic challenge #10: Time

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our tenth topic challenge!

Topic: [time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time)

Dates: 22 June - 4 July

Proposed by:

[image]

> There haven't been very many questions with these tags, but I feel like making them a challenge could result in people thinking in perhaps surprising way about any questions they might have on their mind. time especially is a bit more vague than the challenge topics suggested so far.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

---

**Propose new topics here:** [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

**Previous Challenges**

[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #9: Map-Making](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2199/fortnightly-topic-challenge-9-map-making?rq=1)

[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #8: Apocalypse](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/fortnightly-topic-challenge-8-apocalypse)

[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #7: Economy](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/fortnightly-topic-challenge-7-economy)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #6: Evolution](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/fortnightly-topic-challenge-6-evolution)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #5 : City Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/fortnightly-topic-challenge-5-city-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #4: Magic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/fortnightly-topic-challenge-4-magic)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #3: Creature Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/fortnightly-topic-challenge-3-creature-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #2: Flora](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-flora)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #1: Space](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-space)

Comment: Um . . . A downvote because . . . ?

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but time-travel stuff IMHO brings almost always very poor quality stories and worlds. The fact that one of the few notable exception, Dr. Who, is known for not caring about continuity, should be a huge hint.

Comment: PS: lol you commented **while** I was writing the above explaination

Comment: @Lohoris The place to downvote that is on the suggestions post, which is linked in the question body. Vote on this post based on its merits and its merits alone.

Comment: Hey, it wasn't my choice to do this one. @ArtOfCode I think Lohoris did that; there were two downvotes on that answer. Users can downvote any post they want, including this one; I just thought it was odd, that's all.

Comment: @HDE226868 *full disclosure: one was mine for much the same reasons* - though this post is still not the place to express disapproval, IMO.

Comment: Well, we're on meta, aren't we supposed to just downvote stuff we don't like or disagree with? There's no reputation anyway, so even if you cared about that, no harm was done, right? I've downvoted the linked answer too now, thanks, but I think it's still useful to downvote this post, to show a bit of dislike towards this choice.

Comment: Excellent, problem essentially solved. @Lohoris, now would be a good time to downvote all the other suggestions you dislike - and upvote all the ones you like - to influence decisions on the future via voting. You can still downvote the announcements if you want, but voting on suggestions is also quite efficient.

Comment: Could you edit in the list of past challenges, like in the others?  Thanks.

Comment: Is the challenge a union or an intersection?  If I ask a question about time that's not a question about time-travel, does that count?

Comment: @MonicaCellio given that originally they proposed only [tag:time], I assume that it's a union.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I . . . don't know what overactor had in mind. S/he gave both. Perhaps I'll just limit it to [tag:time].

Comment: @Lohoris Both were proposed at the same time (pun intended).

Comment: @MonicaCellio in challenge 7, [Michael suggested](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/fortnightly-topic-challenge-7-economy#comment4732_2104) we leave the previous topics list to the suggestions post because it'll get so long. That's why I didn't include it in the generator.

Comment: Re the previous posts -- ok, that makes sense!  Sorry I missed the history.  I want us to maintain it *somewhere*, and I noticed that it was in #9 and missing from #10, prompting my comment.  If this is a pattern we've decided to change, sorry for the extra work you did on account of my comment.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'll stop listing them next time, ending the pattern after the first 10.

Comment: Thanks for focusing on just one of the tags.  This process doesn't have to be entirely mechanical; if a suggestion doesn't seem to work quite as proposed, the person organizing the challenge should tweak as needed.  Worst case, we cover the other tag in a later challenge.

Comment: @HDE226868 I've removed the downvote, then!

Comment: How about we just list the last 10 topics, or 5? (Or even 1)

Comment: just discovered that there was a topic challenge for time. if i noticed this earlier, i would have used this tag. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This challenge generated 10 questions and 43 answers, for an average of 4.3 answers per question, counting the 2 closed questions.

**Questions**

1. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19986/rules-magic-for-time-travel-one-way-to-the-past
   (closed)

[image]

2. [What difficulties would there be for society if people could manipulate time?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19953/what-difficulties-would-there-be-for-society-if-people-could-manipulate-time)

[image]

3. [Time no longer passes except near intelligent creatures, how does the world continue?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19834/time-no-longer-passes-except-near-intelligent-creatures-how-does-the-world-cont)

[image]

4. [What traits should we expect from religion in the presence of time loops](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19829/what-traits-should-we-expect-from-religion-in-the-presence-of-time-loops)

[image]

5. [What should I fear/consider if someone asked me today to put me on hibernation and set the time to wake me up 2000 years from now?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19789/what-should-i-fear-consider-if-someone-asked-me-today-to-put-me-on-hibernation-a)
   (closed)

[image]

6. [Can I significantly shorten the days on a planet that can support human life?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19728/can-i-significantly-shorten-the-days-on-a-planet-that-can-support-human-life)

[image]

7. [A Perception Of Time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19719/a-perception-of-time)

[image]

8. [Can you build a relativistic clock?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19607/can-you-build-a-relativistic-clock)

[image]

9. [The Great Time War](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19539/the-great-time-war)

[image]

10. [An immortal's measurement of time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19525/an-immortals-measurement-of-time)

[image]