# Can we make topic challenges Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, challenge

On the [tenth topic challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/fortnightly-topic-challenge-10-time-and-time-travel), just posted, we have some disagreement about the correct places to vote. The important part here is that there is some disagreement, not that it is about votes.

This is, I suspect, not the first time a topic challenge has generated controversy, nor will it be the last. However, our process (such as it exists) for posting topic challenges at the moment lends itself to people getting upset: simply, a user posts the next challenge at the proscribed time, and someone collates the results.

If someone has an issue with a topic challenge, that leaves said user's post being downvoted. If lots of people have the same issue, that user's post gets heavily downvoted. Yes, there is no rep involved here on meta, but nobody likes having heavily downvoted posts under their name.

Conversely, if a post is very well-received, it gets lots of upvotes. OK, we all like those at least, but it's probably not fair to let already-prolific posters here gather more high-scored posts that, in reality, were written by [a machine](http://jenkinsstuff.bl.ee/challenge).

Therefore, a suggestion: we make all TC posts community wiki. Nobody then has their name or profile attached to the posts, and they can be voted on to our hearts' content without fear of offending anyone.

(I ask this only because us regular users can't make *questions* community wiki - only mods. Mods - if we flag posts for conversion to CW, will you object? Any changes/suggestions?)

Comment: I guess I don't particularly care either way.  Both methods should work fine.

Comment: Each topic suggestion should be deleted once it is converted into a "question" announcing that topic challenge. This keeps the topic suggestions question clean. If there are any that haven't been cleaned up in such a manner, then please flag those for moderator attention and include a link to the announcement post.