# Fortnightly topic challenge #11: Religion

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our eleventh topic challenge!

Topic: [religion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion)

Dates: 7 July - 21 July

Proposed by:

[image]

> Simply because it gets omitted so many times when we create new worlds and new societies. I would like to see more of religion questions in set up of fictionary worlds.

Remember to use the [religion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion) tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

---

**Propose new topics here:** [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

**Previous Challenges**

[Fortnightly topic challenge #10: Time](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/fortnightly-topic-challenge-10-time)

[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #9: Map-Making](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2199/fortnightly-topic-challenge-9-map-making?rq=1)

[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #8: Apocalypse](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/fortnightly-topic-challenge-8-apocalypse)

[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #7: Economy](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/fortnightly-topic-challenge-7-economy)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #6: Evolution](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/fortnightly-topic-challenge-6-evolution)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #5 : City Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/fortnightly-topic-challenge-5-city-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #4: Magic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/fortnightly-topic-challenge-4-magic)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #3: Creature Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/fortnightly-topic-challenge-3-creature-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #2: Flora](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-flora)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #1: Space](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-space)

Comment: This is going to be a very touchy subject.

Comment: Thanks for putting this up.

Comment: The topic is sociologically interesting... I cannot help but notice that the downvote rate is something like an order of magnitude higher than usual, especially for answers that criticise religion. But i guess that had to be expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This challenge generated 25 questions and 181 answers, for an average of 7.24 answers per question.

#### Posts

- [Need to start a religion with a predefined self-destruct](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20264/need-to-start-a-religion-with-a-predefined-self-destruct) - [DVK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/634/dvk)
  304 total votes, 47 question votes, 26 answers, 6921 views
- [How could a resurrected Jesus prove he is Jesus without performing miracles?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20238/how-could-a-resurrected-jesus-prove-he-is-jesus) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  145 total votes, 32 question votes, 19 answers, 7256 views
- [Should AI have faith too?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20168/should-ai-have-faith-too) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  113 total votes, 30 question votes, 19 answers, 5593 views
- [How can a god convince a civilization that he doesn't exist?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20130/how-can-a-god-convince-a-civilization-that-he-doesnt-exist) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  102 total votes, 31 question votes, 18 answers, 5608 views
- [Can there be a religious group that will not commit religious violence?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20681/can-there-be-a-religious-group-that-will-not-commit-religious-violence) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  75 total votes, 15 question votes, 15 answers, 3669 views
- [How can I convince members of peaceful religions to start a holy war?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20597/how-can-i-convince-members-of-peaceful-religions-to-start-a-holy-war) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  53 total votes, 9 question votes, 8 answers, 2360 views
- [How can I establish a stable and growing church where everyone is chaste (no sex)?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20249/how-can-i-establish-a-stable-and-growing-church-where-everyone-is-chaste-no-sex) - [DVK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/634/dvk)
  51 total votes, 10 question votes, 15 answers, 575 views
- [Would wars still happen after a Rapture-like event?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/would-wars-still-happen-after-a-rapture-like-event) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  47 total votes, 7 question votes, 12 answers, 2525 views
- [How would people most naturally react to a new god in their *own* polytheistic pantheon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20876/how-would-people-most-naturally-react-to-a-new-god-in-their-own-polytheistic-p) - [Monica Cellio](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/28/monica-cellio)
  35 total votes, 10 question votes, 4 answers, 474 views
- [A Power-Structured Polythesist Religion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20576/a-power-structured-polythesist-religion) - [bilbo_pingouin](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9685/bilbo-pingouin)
  15 total votes, 4 question votes, 7 answers, 143 views
- [How do you protect against granted prayers?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20286/how-do-you-protect-against-granted-prayers) - [DVK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/634/dvk)
  13 total votes, 6 question votes, 6 answers, 166 views
- [Mixing different views on religion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20476/mixing-different-views-on-religion) - [Smajl](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10896/smajl)
  13 total votes, 3 question votes, 3 answers, 102 views
- [How might a religion be used to help maintain a generation ship?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20908/how-might-a-religion-be-used-to-help-maintain-a-generation-ship) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  13 total votes, 5 question votes, 6 answers, 152 views
- [What are the core elements required for creating a "successful" religion?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20153/what-are-the-core-elements-required-for-creating-a-successful-religion) - [DoubleDouble](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2138/doubledouble)
  12 total votes, 0 question votes, 5 answers, 173 views
- [What would be the mythology of an aquatic species?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20565/what-would-be-the-mythology-of-an-aquatic-species) - [JDługosz](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/885/jd%c5%82ugosz)
  12 total votes, 6 question votes, 2 answers, 91 views
- [If religion worked like Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20435/if-religion-worked-like-stack-exchange) - [chasly from UK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10759/chasly-from-uk)
  11 total votes, 11 question votes, 0 answers, 202 views
- [Revealing your religion to be false at the end of a Generation ship trip, or not](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20916/revealing-your-religion-to-be-false-at-the-end-of-a-generation-ship-trip-or-not) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  10 total votes, 2 question votes, 3 answers, 143 views
- [The god of the atheists](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/the-god-of-the-atheists) - [celtschk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/98/celtschk)
  10 total votes, 4 question votes, 3 answers, 157 views
- [Religion for a random god](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20509/religion-for-a-random-god) - [Rob Watts](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6781/rob-watts)
  9 total votes, 3 question votes, 2 answers, 105 views
- [What if AI decided to rule the world through religion?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20331/what-if-ai-decided-to-rule-the-world-through-religion) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  8 total votes, 6 question votes, 2 answers, 179 views
- [What shape would religion take in a world of hallucinations?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20361/what-shape-would-religion-take-in-a-world-of-hallucinations) - [DVK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/634/dvk)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 67 views
- [What would have been if the Islamic religion was never founded?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20749/what-would-have-been-if-the-islamic-religion-was-never-founded) - [user4729](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11031/user4729)
  4 total votes, 4 question votes, 1 answers, 92 views
- [Is it possible to develop early society without developing religion as a side effect?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20372/is-it-possible-to-develop-early-society-without-developing-religion-as-a-side-ef) - [Tim B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b)
  4 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 134 views
- [How would a future British Islam respond to rule by alien mages?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20213/how-would-a-future-british-islam-respond-to-rule-by-alien-mages) - [Lostinfrance](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9207/lostinfrance)
  3 total votes, 3 question votes, 0 answers, 226 views
- [Islam and alien mages?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20573/islam-and-alien-mages) - [Medi Saif](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10913/medi-saif)
  -1 total votes, -2 question votes, 1 answers, 69 views