# Where Do We Go To Make Contests?

Tags: discussion, challenge

As the title suggests, where should we go to make contests?  Are contests, for that matter, even allowed on any of the Stack Exchanges?

For clarification on where I am going with this, let me bring up the [Maps of the Fortnight](https://www.alternatehistory.com/forum/threads/map-of-the-fortnight-main-thread.170373/) series on the Alternate History Forum.  It is a series of map contests regarding alternate history scenarios.  That is pretty much where I am going with this question.

Comment: Like [this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1765/28789)? Or [this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2199/28789)?

Comment: If this is about Great lake earth again, I would advise you not to do it. This is your project, not a community project. Also, this is a question/answer site and while maps are cool, they are only appropriate here if they are part of a question. A map contest would not be appropriate in my opinion.

Comment: @Vincent  People were asking for a world map, which is the whole picture at once.  Since I can't draw and can't actually see mathematic equations, I HAD to ask.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to ask. I'm just trying to figure out what your idea is exactly.

Comment: @Vincent  https://jdailey1991.deviantart.com/journal/Problems-with-Great-Lakes-Earth-s-Map-706992267

Comment: As I thought, it's not appropriate.

Comment: This is your map, you can ask for help but it makes for a poor contest idea. A lot of skilled people are already working on personal projects or for clients. If they do a contest, they do it for fun or to improve skills. Yours have way too many constrains.

Comment: @Vincent  How is it not appropriate?

Comment: Read the comment above. Have you ever participated in a art/mapping contest before? I'm not saying you can't try, I'm just saying that I think it is a bad idea.

Comment: @Vincent  So what else am I supposed to do?

Comment: Assuming you can't find anyone that can help you: 1 learn how to do it yourself. 2 you pay someone to do it for you. That's what people usually do.

Comment: @Vincent  Neither of which is remotely possible.

Comment: Well, if you really like this and if your going to make a lot of maps, it's worth learning it. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a contest, please get "community approval" first.

I read in MSE that [community can decide the policy of what's acceptable themselves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/individual-community-preferences-vs-se-network-policy-who-wins/124915#124915) (some sort of individual states' law in US?), so if an event is approved, go ahead.

> **How to get community approval?**
>
> Simply post a meta, with the details of your event/contest. Of course, if you want approval by the community, provide reasons why you think this is beneficial for the community, instead of just throwing random bounties.
>
> Be prepared **to take criticism.**

For example, in [Interpersonal.SE], we have a [50-day](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/rewarding-the-best-answers-in-the-first-50-days-of-interpersonal-skills) and [100-days](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/100-days-has-gone-by-time-to-reward-your-hard-work) celebration of the IPS site.

In [Writers.SE], we have a Writing Challenge. The user explicitly [ask community approval](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/how-would-having-the-writing-challenges-on-meta-work-out) first before going with the Challenge.

---

Although community can bend SE rules if they agree, if you want your proposal to go through, be cautious if you need to do so. Provide justification why you need to bend the rules (for example: posting a question that usually will be closed as too broad, or too opinion based).

If you decide to use main site, usual rules apply, because we don't want to confuse users about this site scope and rule (except if community agrees to give exception to contest posts).

Thanks for caring about Worldbuilding.SE, and I hope your contest can go well!

Comment: You mentioned Interpersonal and Writers.  What about a Stack Exchange for cartographers?

Comment: @JohnWDailey you mean: https://gis.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, but it is specific for GIS software.

Comment: @johnwdailey Pretty sure there is an Area 51 proposal for a cartography stack exchange.

Comment: @Bellerophon  It's been deleted.