# What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?

Tags: discussion, challenge

Worldbuilding is beginning its [fortnightly topic challenges](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/should-we-have-weekly-topic-challenges). In that [trichoplax wrote](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/should-we-have-weekly-topic-challenges)

> As this question is already being used for answers on how to approach this, would it be clearer to have a separate "Theme suggestions" meta post rather than posting topics as answers here?

This is going to be that post.

So please, post suggestions! Only one per answer, though. The most upvoted answer each fortnight (not counting ones that have already been used) will be used in the next challenge. Heavily downvoted suggestions will not be used. See [this](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/earth-science-biweekly-topic-challenge) Earth Science post.

Note that the answer suggesting a topic will be deleted when that topic is selected, to keep the answer space clean. A list for all to see will be kept under the "previous topics" heading below.

> **Current topic:**
>
> http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/fortnightly-topic-challenge-29-government (21 March - 11 April), suggested by [ASCIIThenANSI](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9498/asciithenansi)

**Previous topics:**

[1 - Space](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1765) |
[2 - Flora](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1810) |
[3 - Creature Design](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1862) |
[4 - Magic](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1916) |
[5 - City Design](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1966) |
[6 - Evolution](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2047/29) |
[7 - Economy](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2104/29) |
[8 - Apocalypse](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2154) |
[9 - Map Making](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2199) |
[10 - Time](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2242) |
[11 - Religion](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2262) |
[12 - Humans](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2323) |
[13 - Weapon Design](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2386) |
[14 - Hard Science](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2454) |
[15 - Worldbuilding Process](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2548) |
[16 - Warfare](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2612) |
[17 - Moons](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2644) |
[18 - Architecture](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2688)|
[19 - Politics](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2718) |
[20 - Language](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2756/fortnightly-challenge-20-language) |
[21 - Underwater](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/fortnightly-challenge-21-underwater) |
[22 - Geography](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/fortnightly-topic-challenge-22-geography) |
[23 - Santa](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2860/fortnightly-topic-challenge-23-santa) |
[24 - Near Future](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2883/fortnightly-topic-challenge-24-near-future) |
[25 - Culture and Society](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2911/fortnightly-topic-challenge-25-culture-and-society) |
[26 - Mythical Creatures](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2985/fortnightly-topic-challenge-26-mythical-creatures) |
[27 - History](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3172/fortnightly-topic-challenge-27-history) |
[28 - Calendar](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/fortnightly-topic-challenge-28-calendar)

**[Question/Answer Generator](http://jenkinsstuff.bl.ee/challenge/#):**
Provided by [ArtOfCode](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2685/artofcode) for quick and easy generation of challenge questions and answers.

#### Update on April 12th:

http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/should-we-end-the-topic-challenges answer: regular fortnightly challenge is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 15):

[medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval)

I'd like to see a load of medieval questions, not only because of their context, but because of the wide variety of other categories that frequently entail questions of such a foundation. These include magic and war, which just add to the depth of which our answers must reach to satisfy the hungry, medieval beast that is the OP. I think, if we encourage the use of it through a contest, we could get some highly refined, difficult to answer questions out of this tag.

It might be based on things that happened hundreds of years ago, but [medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval) continues to hold a lot of potential for great questions and even better answers.

Answer (score 15):

[relativity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relativity)

People are often saddened by the fact you can't move faster than light, and therefore sort of write relativity out of their stories. What they don't understand is the *rich* structure of relativity and what it allows you to do. For example, completely legit relativity *does* allow you to have a galactic empire (although it would take a lot of energy) (the trick is time dilation). It is surely stranger than fiction. Making this a fortnightly challenge would allow people to learn all the *awesome* stuff relativity allows you to do.

Answer (score 14):

[gender](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender)

While this opens up a lot of possibilities and debate, it is not contentious in this particular site, like it would be on Youtube comments or whatever.  I think this would be exciting, because we're talking about past/future, alternate reality, or alien civilization; among other things.  This is one of our tags, and this is one of the few sites where it can be discussed maturely.  If not, why is it a tag?

Comment: I think you're opening up a can of worms that this site is not prepared to deal with. You're going to have tons and tons of comment debates about wether a given ideology is true, whose opinions are best, etc. Prople will have different views, and the questions are likely to degrade into arguments. This may not actually happen, but that is what I **think** will.

Comment: Ah @XandarTheZenon - you may be right, but I thought this SE was more mature.  Also, when I look at the tag, the questions and answers have been very mature.  I think it would illicit good questions and answers.  We should not be afraid to ask questions about gender just because non-WB people like to argue about them.

Comment: All right, but depending on the context of the questions some problems might still arise. Upon further inspection, most of those questions do seem relatively sane.

Comment: This is one of those topics about which we will need to be very disciplined. Answers will arrive that are pure opinion, based on no actual knowledge of the subject. These will have to be ruthlessly down-voted, with the explanation being that they're just opinion. If that sounds unlikely (or just very unpleasant), then this isn't a good topic.

Comment: @CAgrippa - agreed; but that's partly why I selected it.  I know of few forums that can tackle this in a worldbuilding sense while remaining vigilant at self-moderation.  You're right about the Opinion-Based issue.   ... Still, some of our stories need help tackling gender: what better place to get community input?  Also - City Design was already taken ;)

Comment: @Mikey - My concern isn't so much about opinion-based questions, but answers. Someone asks how gender might be constructed in a world in which primary and secondary sexual characteristics are not visible (because of clothing, etc.). Someone replies, but seems not to know anything about what "gender construction" is. Answers like that have to be challenged, and hard, or the people asking questions won't learn anything -- and nor will the rest of the community.

Comment: @CAgrippa - the questions already tagged gender have a lot of votes, a lot of upvoted answers, and a lot of accepted answers.  I did LOL that this suggested tag has the most upvotes AND the most downvotes AND the most comments - so maybe you're right!

Answer (score 14):

[communication](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication)

Because without communication, it would be a lonely world.

Answer (score 14):

[food](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food)

Because the subject of nourishment and food in general (sources, processing, storage, quantities, etc) is a vital part of world-building and species-building.

This tag could generate questions in relation to biology, culture, religion, society, technology and more.

Answer (score 12):

[terraforming](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraforming)

We usually build our own worlds from scratch. Having to use certain features in a pre-built world and changing them to what is needed requires a whole different approach for both characters and their creator.

Alternatively, we can build a world and let it be up to the characters to change it.

Answer (score 12):

[steampunk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steampunk)

Gaslit Victoriana. Copper, brass and smoke everywhere. C'mon, steampunk worlds are so different from our own!

Answer (score 11):

[alternate-world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-world)

Because they are often interesting to answer and are typically a greater challenge than others due to the speculative answers it can attract.

Comment: Mind the distinction between this and the earth-like tag

Answer (score 10):

I am going to recommend a repeat tag.  [religion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion) was a fantastic topic for the fortnightly challenge.

The questions are generally interesting and always generate significant interest and passion.  Last time we were slightly worried about it being too contentious but things remained civil.

Would enjoy this topic coming up again.

Comment: So would I, but we have to be a little careful. Interest and passion is good, but everyone waving around uninformed opinions is not. Answers need to be rooted in knowledge, most likely in the form of researched examples.

Answer (score 10):

How about [slavery](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slavery)? After all we only have 7 slavery questions on the site, it would be interesting to see what else the community can come up with

Comment: Is there a tag for that?

Comment: yeah there is; https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slavery

Comment: I *love* slavery!

Comment: Goodness! I of all people should know that there is a slavery tag. What a joyous institution... Not...

Comment: I think this is an interesting tag because here it opens up possibilities like "How could humans enslave an alien race?" or something similar.

Answer (score 9):

[interspecies-relations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interspecies-relations)! Do a challenge on those!

Comment: We'd need a specific tag though (preferably one that already exists).

Comment: New Tag Relationships

Comment: We do have [interspecies-relations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interspecies-relations), since quite a while ago. Is that the one you were aiming for? (Please edit your post using the `[tag:something]` syntax to indicate which tag you are proposing we use for a challenge.)

Answer (score 8):

[zombies](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombies)

I wont vote for Rome, because i spend my whole set of questions about Rome today. But i believe Zombies can get a go.

Comment: Roman zombies ?

Comment: Good one. I will think about the consequences of a Roman zombie outbreak :P

Comment: I might very well ask about the consequences of a Wizard who can casts spells that turn people into zombies, during the Roman times...

Comment: @JorgeAldo You can't go wrong with zombie.....until you do.

Comment: [Romero zombies.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_A._Romero)

Comment: @JorgeAldo What about the zombie outbreak near [Fanum Cocidi, Caledonia](http://zombie.wikia.com/wiki/121_A.D.,_Fanum_Cocidi,_Caledonia_(Scotland)) that the Roman legion led by Marcus Lucius Terentius had to put down?

Answer (score 8):

[psionics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psionics)

is an unused tag, which could bring interesting ideas.

A science-fiction setting with a little drop of magic in it. I think that psionic capabilities can add a lot to different worlds for a relatively cheap price in term of balance of the whole world. And for that we should explore it more.

Answer (score 8):

[blacksmithing](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blacksmithing) ok minor edit, the proper form for this tag would be [forging](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forging) which actually exists on the site  (as of now)

I recently signed up for an intro course to learn to blacksmith, as many worlds are medieval it seems an interesting and appropriate topic.

Not to mention one of my all time favorite chapters in any fiction book was the scene in Eragon where he and the elf forge him a new sword.

Comment: Nice idea. I think you and bowlturner will be some of the go-to people on this one.

Comment: @HDE226868 Hopefully this doesnt get selected until August then (that's when I have my class :)

Answer (score 8):

[mythical-creatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythical-creatures) in combination with [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) or [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) for those not comfortable with hard science.

It's a more specific challenge and the goal is to see whether or not it's possible to explain the proprieties of a fictional creature with science. Sometimes a "no, it's not possible" is a perfectly valid answer and the question is not bad because of this.

Answer (score 7):

[atmosphere](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere)

The atmosphere is a fairly essential part of any world, and this should be reflected by use of this tag. Since the atmosphere is important, but often ignored, I think that questions that focus on it could have potential.

Answer (score 7):

[sex](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex)

Of all the animals on earth, humans appear to spend the most time thinking about it and doing it.  Aside from bonobos, who go to even greater extremes than us, there are practically no other animals which seem as obsessed with sex as humans.  Just look at the internet; when you have to have special filters to keep sexually-related results off the results list, you know that it's a big topic.  Despite that degree of importance, as of the moment I write this, this tag has only two questions.

Given that humans are so obsessed with sex, there are plenty of ways that sexuality can affect a world.

Comment: Relevant xkcd: http://xkcd.com/1564/.

Comment: Hah!  Now we have 7 [tag:sex] questions.

Comment: I don't think this topic is really appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

[chemistry](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry)

i don't see many questions with this tag although it is important in many aspects of our lives.

Answer (score 6):

[fauna](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fauna) I am surprised we don't have a fauna request.  We had Flora months ago!  Need to fill the story with little beasties to pet, fight and eat!

Comment: I want more questions like this.

Answer (score 6):

[diseases](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diseases)

Diseases can be downright terrifying if portrayed accurately. How they spread, how they work, how people react to them...

Comment: Philip the expectation is a single tag, please select one and remove the other from your suggestion.  Thanks

Comment: No problem @James

Answer (score 5):

[oxygen](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oxygen)

Because getting 20+ questions about oxygen requires a good deal of creativity.

Comment: Second that do I. [deep inhale]

Answer (score 5):

[shapeshifters](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapeshifters)

Because they are a staple in certain types of fiction works, yet tend to only get cursory attention. We already have some questions about them; giving them their two weeks of fame could prove interesting.

Note the similarity to the [already proposed mythical-creatures challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2245/29) -- "shapeshifters" can probably be considered a subtag of "mythical-creatures".

Answer (score 4):

[units](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units) [measurement](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement)
[currency](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) [money](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money)

Of these tags, only `currency` already exists, but doesn’t world building often include the design of a custom system of measurement and units, which are often linked to coinage?

Comment: Crissov the challenge is generally tied to a single tag.  Can you narrow it down?

Comment: Economics is probably a better tag

Answer (score 4):

[alternate-history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-history)

Altering history is dangerous. You can accidentally destroy the Earth or cause yourself to never be born. Which is why we need a safe way to talk about what would happen if things were different.

Answer (score 3):

[travel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel)

Where would we go if we couldn't travel? Nowhere of course!

Answer (score 2):

[futurology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurology)

Because it's just too darn fun!

Answer (score 2):

[energy-beings](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-beings) While specific, there's quite a few of them in literature and not much is know about how they work or what they do.

Comment: We don't actually have that tag yet.

Comment: Yep. But I guess the formatting works anyway? Anyway, the first question can make it. I have a few ideas...

Comment: I guess. Do you really want to start a topic challenge on a tag that doesn't yet exist? Scratch that, actually. If you can start some good questions and establish the topic, this could be an interesting one.

Comment: Watch the sandbox. I'll work on a few.

Comment: I'm looking forward to them :-)

Comment: We now have one question tagged energy-beings...

Comment: bad flash backs to the ending of 2001: A Space Odyssey

Answer (score 2):

How about [planetary-rings](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary-rings) ? they don't get much attention.

Answer (score 2):

[cuisine](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cuisine)

Sometimes one needs to sit back, relax and enjoy a good meal. Why wouldn't the inhabitants of our worlds do it as well? How to build an exotic cuisine for an exotic world?

Comment: Note that we have a [tag:food] tag, so if this challenge gets used, we should use that tag rather than creating cuisine.  (I realize that a comment I made about alien cuisine probably prompted this answer.)

Answer (score 2):

[industrial-history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industrial-history)

While exploring James's [history tags question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/what-shall-we-do-with-the-history-tags/3184#3184), I discovered this tag and think it's fascinating. The Industrial Era was a hotspot of innovation and development, and I feel that there's loads of potential for industrial innovations in new and unique worlds.

Answer (score 1):

[lithosphere](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithosphere)

A new look at spheres. Atmo-, bio- and exo- have gotten enough attention.
From the ground up^Wdown: How would a planet with an interesting layering have to be designed? Bring plenty of [unobtainium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtainium)!

Comment: Suggestions should be tags that are already established, i.e. have already been created.

Answer (score 1):

[biotech](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biotech) [bio-mechanics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bio-mechanics) [genetic-engineering](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genetic-engineering) [cybernetics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cybernetics) [trans-humanism](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trans-humanism)

Evolution was already a topic; I'd be really interested to see questions more focused on body modification, long-term goals for genetic engineering *(why bother terraforming a planet if you could live on its surface without a suit -- but what kind of physiology would that require?)*, etc.

Comment: I like this suggestion but we need just one tag per suggestion...

Comment: @TimB: Ah ok... maybe genetic-engineering would be the best one, then.

Comment: Well if you had two answers, one for genetic engineering and one for cybernetics I'd upvote both :)

Answer (score 0):

[unobtainium](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unobtainium)

If Kirk saw push coming to shove, Scotty would **modulate the phaser frequency**.
If Luke had to act hogwartsy, he'd **use the force**.

The plot device for world builders: **unobtainium**, the right stuff with that property you need but chemists haven't found to this day and which makes physicists throw fits.

Comment: I would argue that a part of what we do is to try to help people *avoid* using unobtainium. :-)

Answer (score -1):

[fishing](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishing)

Fish are delicious.

Comment: I'm surprised we don't have a [tag:fish] tag. All I can find is [tag:underwater], and, as you suggested, [tag:fishing]. We should definitely have a fish tag.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh tags are (err) organic; when we have questions that warrant them we should create them.  Do we have questions specifically about *fish* that are ill-served by the broader *underwater* tag?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh You could ask a [tag:fish] question.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Well, there are a lot of underwater questions combined with other tags, like biology or creature-design or evolution, which might make sense under a fish tag. But I guess I just like saying 'fish'.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh If you put tags that don't exist in your questions using \[tag:fish\], high rep users tend to create them. Thats how [tag:fishing] was created.

Comment: This is a spam guys.Fish are delicious?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Late to the game, but there are plenty of underwater creatures that aren't fish. We could start with dolphins...

Answer (score -1):

[mathematics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics)
Alternate mathematics. This is an interesting tag with great potential, but it isn't used much.

Comment: You really can't change the fundamentals of mathematics much. It's easy to change how those fundamentals are *expressed*, but like with so many questions on the form "what happens to X if I change fundamental aspect Y of our universe such that Z?", the answer to questions about truly *alternate* mathematics tends to be "everything breaks".

Comment: @MichaelKjörling there are ways to do it without breaking everything, i.e. changing the distance formula