# In the fortnightly topic challenges, how to choose between identically voted suggestions?

Tags: discussion, challenge

I think this is something that is best hashed out ahead of time. In our [fortnightly topic challenge topics suggestion question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1768/29), we currently have three suggestions all ranking as #2 when sorted by net votes.

To make sure the choice isn't completely arbitrary, **how should we decide which one to pick** when multiple alternatives all have the same (highest) net vote score by community voting?

Answer (score 6):

I'm actually ok with a little arbitrariness.  On some sites I've seen a moderately-voted suggestion get picked over higher-voted ones because it's in some way topical *that week*.  That's fine too.

So long as it's broadly matching the will of the community, I'm happy to let the person who's doing the work make choices in the case of ties or to *occasionally* choose something farther down the list for a good, stated reason.

Comment: Bow to the whims of the poster!!!!  Bwahahaha.  Ok but seriously, if they are equally voted they will all get their shot.  I think this concern is a rather small problem if a problem at all.  *"Oh no!  We have to many good ideas!"* :)

Answer (score 3):

Pick the one among the equally-net-voted alternatives that was **posted the earliest** according to the answer's "answered" timestamp.

It's easy to compare the timestamps, everyone has access to the information (and thus can verify the choice if they feel so inclined), the risk of collisions is minimal (equally net voted *and* top net voted *and* posted the same second seems incredibly unlikely to me) and they will all get their turn eventually.