# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #13: Weapon-Design

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our thirteenth topic challenge!

Topic: [weapon-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapon-design)

Dates: 3 Aug - 17 Aug

Proposed by:

[image]

> Because I, for one, just loooove ka-boom-boom. After all, who doesn't?

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

---

**Propose new topics here:** [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Comment: As someone who's asked 8% of the current [tag:weapon-design] questions so far (20% of my total questions), I am looking forward to this one.

Comment: Hah, over half of my questions are tagged with this. But you beat me by 1% >< lol @DaaaahWhoosh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This challenge generated 43 questions and 210 answers, for an average of 4.88 answers per question.

#### Posts

- [Wooden sticks are the only allowed weapons in a technological society - how far would these weapons have progressed by now?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21814/wooden-sticks-are-the-only-allowed-weapons-in-a-technological-society-how-far) - [chasly from UK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10759/chasly-from-uk)
  209 total votes, 33 question votes, 20 answers, 8116 views
  [image: Vote Hunter (gold badge): over 200 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Idea Generation (gold badge): 20 answers on your question] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [How can I liquefy my enemies?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21908/how-can-i-liquefy-my-enemies) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  177 total votes, 29 question votes, 17 answers, 7614 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Mosquito Assassin: What is the most deadly substance that can be injected into someone?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21921/mosquito-assassin-what-is-the-most-deadly-substance-that-can-be-injected-into-s) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  160 total votes, 30 question votes, 12 answers, 6631 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [How to make a 2D image which kills people who see it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21951/how-to-make-a-2d-image-which-kills-people-who-see-it) - [DoubleDouble](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2138/doubledouble)
  107 total votes, 22 question votes, 20 answers, 6531 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Idea Generation (gold badge): 20 answers on your question] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Perfect weapon for two-elbow creature](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22563/perfect-weapon-for-two-elbow-creature) - [Darth Hunterix](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3254/darth-hunterix)
  95 total votes, 23 question votes, 12 answers, 3400 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What would be the ideal melee weapon for someone with superhuman strength?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22124/what-would-be-the-ideal-melee-weapon-for-someone-with-superhuman-strength) - [vsz](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/262/vsz)
  54 total votes, 22 question votes, 10 answers, 1616 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Can I grow a banana that will produce mushroom cloud?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21826/can-i-grow-a-banana-that-will-produce-mushroom-cloud) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  53 total votes, 12 question votes, 5 answers, 3810 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Lightning Rifle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22347/lightning-rifle) - [Culyx](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/366/culyx)
  51 total votes, 14 question votes, 3 answers, 2017 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers]
- [Let's Weaponize Frogs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22426/lets-weaponize-frogs) - [WhyEnBe](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10778/whyenbe)
  37 total votes, 11 question votes, 6 answers, 2050 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Can I create an unstoppable disease?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21750/can-i-create-an-unstoppable-disease) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  36 total votes, 11 question votes, 5 answers, 2218 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Handheld weapons, plasma vs. laser](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22312/handheld-weapons-plasma-vs-laser) - [Llama_guy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11564/llama-guy)
  34 total votes, 9 question votes, 3 answers, 1819 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers]
- [How will my nerdy Mars astronauts do battle between their colonies?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22573/how-will-my-nerdy-mars-astronauts-do-battle-between-their-colonies) - [Mikey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey)
  32 total votes, 10 question votes, 5 answers, 607 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Chemical propellant free automatic weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21763/chemical-propellant-free-automatic-weapons) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  30 total votes, 6 question votes, 5 answers, 934 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How to make a Sound Gun](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21822/how-to-make-a-sound-gun) - [DaaaahWhoosh](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6507/daaaahwhoosh)
  28 total votes, 8 question votes, 4 answers, 1074 views
- [Hypnosis as a weapon in the war against terror. How could it be delivered?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21892/hypnosis-as-a-weapon-in-the-war-against-terror-how-could-it-be-delivered) - [chasly from UK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10759/chasly-from-uk)
  19 total votes, 6 question votes, 3 answers, 608 views
- [Scorpions as living handgrenades](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22660/scorpions-as-living-handgrenades) - [Pavel V.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/95/pavel-v)
  17 total votes, 5 question votes, 5 answers, 182 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How can a dragon utilize antimatter in combat?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22006/how-can-a-dragon-utilize-antimatter-in-combat) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  15 total votes, 3 question votes, 3 answers, 217 views
- [We finally have a weapon to win the war against the aliens. We don't know how to deploy it](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21840/we-finally-have-a-weapon-to-win-the-war-against-the-aliens-we-dont-know-how-to) - [Aify](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6453/aify)
  14 total votes, 2 question votes, 5 answers, 663 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [A Weapon To Control The Population](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21786/a-weapon-to-control-the-population) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  13 total votes, 7 question votes, 4 answers, 125 views
- [What would medieval battles look like if humans had fully prehensile tails?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22069/what-would-medieval-battles-look-like-if-humans-had-fully-prehensile-tails) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  13 total votes, 7 question votes, 5 answers, 329 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What about electronic warfare?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22641/what-about-electronic-warfare) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  12 total votes, 5 question votes, 2 answers, 77 views
- [Process for creating cultural weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22176/process-for-creating-cultural-weapons) - [Frostfyre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6986/frostfyre)
  12 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 111 views
- [How can I vaporize my enemies?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21966/how-can-i-vaporize-my-enemies) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  10 total votes, 4 question votes, 3 answers, 124 views
- [Question about non-lethal weapon for large number of people](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22214/question-about-non-lethal-weapon-for-large-number-of-people) - [Satori Wita](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11414/satori-wita)
  10 total votes, 4 question votes, 8 answers, 166 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Personal issue handheld 3D printer during wartime](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22082/personal-issue-handheld-3d-printer-during-wartime) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  10 total votes, 4 question votes, 3 answers, 108 views
- [Using depleted uranium weapons in medieval battle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22392/using-depleted-uranium-weapons-in-medieval-battle) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  10 total votes, 2 question votes, 3 answers, 114 views
- [How can I create sonic boom using personalized katana?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22310/how-can-i-create-sonic-boom-using-personalized-katana) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  9 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 102 views
- [An assault rifle that can fire homing rounds?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22320/an-assault-rifle-that-can-fire-homing-rounds) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  7 total votes, 1 question votes, 5 answers, 123 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Is it possible to create a bio-weapon that targets a certain group of people without risk of spreading beyond them?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21926/is-it-possible-to-create-a-bio-weapon-that-targets-a-certain-group-of-people-wit) - [dsollen](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/4857/dsollen)
  6 total votes, 3 question votes, 2 answers, 84 views
- [How (in)effective would a Tesla coil be as a static defence weapon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22222/how-ineffective-would-a-tesla-coil-be-as-a-static-defence-weapon) - [Philip Rowlands](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7076/philip-rowlands)
  6 total votes, 3 question votes, 1 answers, 157 views
- [Is it possible to engineer a sperm whale into a submarine killer?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22071/is-it-possible-to-engineer-a-sperm-whale-into-sub-killer) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  6 total votes, 5 question votes, 1 answers, 100 views
- [Is freeze ray possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22388/is-freeze-ray-possible) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  6 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 100 views
- [Air robots for law enforcement trial period](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21811/air-robots-for-law-enforcement-trial-period) - [bilbo_pingouin](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9685/bilbo-pingouin)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 67 views
- [energy based super weapons in space, realistically possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22434/energy-based-super-weapons-in-space-realistically-possible) - [Nonafel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11608/nonafel)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 204 views
- [What kind of technology is required to part water?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22150/what-kind-of-technology-is-required-to-part-water) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  5 total votes, 0 question votes, 4 answers, 219 views
- [Can we arm RFID?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21927/can-we-arm-rfid) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  4 total votes, -1 question votes, 3 answers, 108 views
- [Weaponizing the reverse assembly or partial disintegration of matter](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22577/weaponizing-the-reverse-assembly-or-partial-disintegration-of-matter) - [Nonafel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11608/nonafel)
  4 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 77 views
- [Would the gravitational waves a binary black hole system make a feasible weapon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21773/would-the-gravitational-waves-a-binary-black-hole-system-make-a-feasible-weapon) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  4 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 94 views
- [Is it possible to rain dinosaurs?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22151/is-it-possible-to-rain-dinosaurs) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  2 total votes, 0 question votes, 1 answers, 59 views
- [How does the medieval militants use mirror as weapon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22323/how-does-the-medieval-militants-use-mirror-as-weapon) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  2 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 77 views
- [Project Hide of Leviathan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21883/project-hide-of-leviathan) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  2 total votes, 0 question votes, 1 answers, 43 views
- [How can medieval knights hunt down a spinosaurus using nothing but lance?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22168/how-can-medieval-knights-hunt-down-a-spinosaurus-using-nothing-but-lance) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  2 total votes, 1 question votes, 1 answers, 68 views
- [General Purpose Machine Gun Ring Planet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22164/general-purpose-machine-gun-ring-planet) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  1 total votes, 0 question votes, 1 answers, 38 views

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to point out that during the two weeks of this challenge, according to [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300932/asked-closed-reopened-per-week#resultSets), we had the highest(105) and third highest(97) number of questions asked in a week in the entire history of the site. We also had the top two weeks of closed questions(38 and 23). I have a feeling the challenge had a hand in these numbers.

Comment: I love how the challenge brought us highest questions asked in a week, and i think a closer look at the closed questions might be able to show us our underlying problem of distinguishing between idea generation and "ok". Is there any way to get stats on the closed questions specifically?

Comment: @Aify I could write up a query for it, what stats do you want?

Comment: I'm not sure what stats are available to get. However, I would love to at least see the relationship between question status and age of the account (or rep of the user, or both), for one. Also, possibly how long it remained open, and whether or not the closing was unanimous. Oh, and the tags most often used in the closed questions (minus the obvious weapon design)

Comment: @Aify [Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/353426) is what I came up with so far. I think 19 and 5 are the right parameters today. I couldn't think of a good way to order the columns, so you'll have to mess around with it to get what you're looking for.

Comment: You've messed up on the last requirement (but that was my fault for being unclear) - I meant what the OTHER tags in conjunction with the weapon design tag that is most used (ignoring the fact that obviously, weapon design will be on all of them). lol

Comment: @Aify Yeah, I couldn't think of a good way to manage that one. Tags are a many-to-one relation to questions, which makes it hard to get detailed tag data *and* useful user data. And I was trying to make the query more general, since it may prove useful in other cases (for instance, congrats on not having a closed question). I might make another query to deal with tags if I have the time.