# Topic Challenges - Badges

Tags: discussion, challenge, badges

As you [may](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2385/2685) [have](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2453/2685) [seen](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2551/2685), the topic challenge results are now handing out badges for various things! (OK, not *real* badges - they don't get applied to your profile, but close enough.) We currently have:

[image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers]
[image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers]
[image: Vote Hunter (gold badge): over 200 total upvotes on question and answers]

[image: Shot Down (bronze badge): total score of less than 0 on question and answers]

[image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
[image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
[image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]

[image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
[image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question]
[image: Idea Generation (gold badge): 20 answers on your question]

(descriptions in the tooltips if you hover on them)

(plus one secret badge that hasn't been awarded yet)

That's a fair few, but I'd like to see more. In the answers here, propose a badge (or badges), along with its tier (bronze/silver/gold) and requirements that you'd like to see added to the challenge badges.

At some as-yet-undefined threshold of community approval through votes, I'll add the badges to the generator.

Comment: For a second, I thought you'd made "Shot Down" as a tribute to The Clash's "Guns of Brixton", but I immediately dismissed that as sheer lunacy brought on by heat. This is a really neat idea, by the way.

Comment: @HDE226868 I was going to say I'm not old enough to know of it, then realised both that I don't know how old it is, and that I'm older than you are :)

Comment: It's [35 years old (36 in December)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guns_of_Brixton).

Answer (score 3):

How about badges for **ratio of votes per views**?

Statistically, a question that attracts many views will have more upvotes, but I am not sure it is always related...

To get some idea to place the threshold, I used the results you had for the last [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) challenge to produce the following
[image: ratio votes-views]

The dashed curves on the right sides are 1st-order linear fits.

I am not sure whether we should take the total vote (red on the graphs) or the question vote (blue). The question vote is probably less biased as a viewer can vote for a question and for the answers. But the total vote also give prices to very good answers. YMMV.

Just for the sake of it, I made the following

[image: Relation between the number of votes on questions and the total number of votes]

where the dashed line is a log fit (elimitating the highest point).

Comment: Could you label your axii please?  It's hard to figure out what those graph indicate otherwise.

Comment: I deleted the files... ^^" I thought it would be clear. So x axis is the ratio #vote/#views. And y axis is the count. This is an histogram. I'll see if I get get some time to reproduce those, but you get the idea anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  If you get the time, I'd be curious to see the scatter plot between Views and Up Votes for answers.

Comment: Ok, I took 5 minutes and made it again. Hope you like it :-)

Comment: The dashed lines are a crude linear (1st order) fit on the whole set. To get and idea, due to the log-scale.

Comment: I do!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## Number of questions

This is a badge that does not go to questions as such, but to users. Some users are particularly prolific on some topics and maybe the first one might receive a badge. Maybe not more than one because we prefer quality over quantity. But nevertheless it might be interesting to mark it.

For example, out of 20 questions for the [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process), Vincent asked 6 himself. And for [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science), out of 33 questions, user6760 asked 12.

Comment: Yes,we prefer quality over quantity but up-votes and quality are loosely correlated. My opinion. http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/12395/147

Comment: @Vincent, sure. But having many badges for those who ask many questions may get people to ask many questions, instead of making sure they get one or two good. I think it is still interesting to mark the one who had more questions... maybe if two have the same number of questions, it could be decided on the accumulated number of questions vote. So that not only one needs to ask many questions, but also making sure they are good.

Answer (score 2):

Controversy

The number of up-votes and down-votes on your answer/question is nearly equal (less than a difference of 2 votes on either side)

Bronze (5-7 up-votes and 5-7 down-votes for the same question/answer)

Silver (10-12 up-votes and 10-12 down-votes for the same question/answer)

Gold (15 or more up-votes and 15 or more down-votes with a net difference less than 3)

Of course we (members) can't really count up and down votes on our posts (we can only see the net result) but mods can.

Comment: When you reach 500 rep, you can see vote counts.

Comment: The member(s) winning this badge might be novices. They might not even know such a challenge is in place :D

Comment: Aye, but only the person compiling the results needs to look at the counts - and even then they only need to if the generator fails.

Comment: Sounds like a plan ;)