# Fortnightly topic challenge #14: Hard Science

Tags: discussion, challenge

**Now begins our fourteenth topic challenge!**

Topic: [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science)

**Please keep in mind that asking hard science questions requires enough information to allow people to answer with, math, science or peer reviewed studies.**

Dates: 17 Aug - 31 Aug

Proposed by:

[image]

> This is a new tag and we need it to get some visibility. We also need to find out how good we are at using it properly. Now is the time to do that :-)

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Comment: A challenge worthy of my skill!

Comment: Ooo, that's going to be a tricky one.

Answer (score 4):

This challenge generated 33 questions and 100 answers, for an average of 3.03 answers per question.

#### Posts

- [Can stars that are not powered by nuclear fusion exist?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22769/can-stars-exist-that-are-not-powered-by-nuclear-fusion) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  93 total votes, 42 question votes, 11 answers, 4800 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [Blind spot in the Solar System](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23237/blind-spot-in-the-solar-system) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  93 total votes, 17 question votes, 11 answers, 4272 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Stealth in Space: How realistic is it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23313/stealth-in-space-how-realistic-is-it) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  86 total votes, 23 question votes, 11 answers, 3680 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [With current technology, what would be the best way to store energy for future generations?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23118/with-current-technology-what-would-be-the-best-way-to-store-energy-for-future-g) - [DoubleDouble](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2138/doubledouble)
  59 total votes, 12 question votes, 10 answers, 1129 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [The last ride of The Magic Schoolbus: Termination of the ignorant](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22862/the-last-ride-of-the-magic-schoolbus-termination-of-the-ignorant) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  21 total votes, 10 question votes, 1 answers, 173 views
- [Design me a Mars drone](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23011/design-me-a-mars-drone) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  15 total votes, 10 question votes, 4 answers, 180 views
- [How would you designate targets for orbital bombardment?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23284/how-would-you-designate-targets-for-orbital-bombardment) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  13 total votes, 5 question votes, 5 answers, 323 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Would it be possible to use the earth's rotation to launch spaceships to other planets?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23127/would-it-be-possible-to-use-the-earths-rotation-to-launch-spaceships-to-other-p) - [Tim B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b)
  13 total votes, 5 question votes, 1 answers, 224 views
- [The Babbage Probe](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23235/the-babbage-probe) - [Scott Downey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/1989/scott-downey)
  12 total votes, 5 question votes, 3 answers, 571 views
- [Can you add a mini moon to Earth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23452/can-you-add-a-mini-moon-to-earth) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  12 total votes, 8 question votes, 3 answers, 177 views
- [Can medieval people make a potato gun?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23168/can-medieval-people-make-a-potato-gun) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  12 total votes, 6 question votes, 1 answers, 109 views
- [If Mars contains coal, will it becomes dominant source of energy?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23397/if-mars-contains-coal-will-it-becomes-dominant-source-of-energy) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  11 total votes, 2 question votes, 3 answers, 128 views
- [Large spider walking upside down](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22806/large-spider-walking-upside-down) - [Vincent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/147/vincent)
  11 total votes, 3 question votes, 2 answers, 106 views
- [How to render a large percentage of humans infertile?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22863/how-to-render-a-large-percentage-of-humans-infertile) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  10 total votes, 8 question votes, 4 answers, 118 views
- [Cloth-eating creature wants to eat synthetic textiles. How?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22765/cloth-eating-creature-wants-to-eat-synthetic-textiles-how) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  7 total votes, 4 question votes, 1 answers, 64 views
- [What is the best planetary orbit around a black hole in order to support life?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22795/what-is-the-best-planetary-orbit-around-a-black-hole-in-order-to-support-life) - [chasly from UK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10759/chasly-from-uk)
  7 total votes, 4 question votes, 2 answers, 155 views
- [Targeting cities with meteors](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22781/targeting-cities-with-meteors) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  7 total votes, 6 question votes, 3 answers, 124 views
- [How to make a flying human](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23145/how-to-make-a-flying-human) - [celtschk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/98/celtschk)
  7 total votes, 3 question votes, 1 answers, 80 views
- [Creating a realistic world(s) map - Stars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23040/creating-a-realistic-worlds-map-stars) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  6 total votes, 6 question votes, 0 answers, 98 views
- [Close the door on your way out - Life lit by a blue dwarf star](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23183/close-the-door-on-your-way-out-life-lit-by-a-blue-dwarf-star) - [rumguff](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11859/rumguff)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 103 views
- [How can future Mars colonists combat intelligence loss?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23402/how-can-future-mars-colonists-combat-intelligence-loss) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  5 total votes, 3 question votes, 3 answers, 127 views
- [Silent low altitude long range supersonic drone](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22834/silent-low-altitude-long-range-supersonic-drone) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 94 views
- [Targeting cities with meteors (part 2)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22861/targeting-cities-with-meteors-part-2) - [Bobson](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/50/bobson)
  5 total votes, 4 question votes, 1 answers, 89 views
- [A spacecraft the size of Apollo 11's lunar module, composed of antimatter, around a normal star](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23646/a-spacecraft-the-size-of-apollo-11s-lunar-module-composed-of-antimatter-aroun) - [Hendrik Lie](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7974/hendrik-lie)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 66 views
- [Turning moon into a solar panels](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22824/turning-moon-into-a-solar-panels) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  5 total votes, 1 question votes, 3 answers, 82 views
- [How to effectively survey alien planet for complex lifeforms?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23316/how-to-effectively-survey-alien-planet-for-complex-lifeforms) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  3 total votes, 1 question votes, 1 answers, 60 views
- [What minerals can be used to make teeth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/what-minerals-can-be-used-to-make-teeth) - [Monty Wild](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/75/monty-wild)
  3 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 36 views
- [Fending against asteriod assembled using only Lego® bricks](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22924/fending-against-asteriod-assembled-using-only-lego%c2%ae-bricks) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  2 total votes, -1 question votes, 1 answers, 85 views
- [What would our world be like if we only had knowledge of mathematics up to (and including) precalculus?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23243/what-would-our-world-be-like-if-we-only-had-knowledge-of-mathematics-up-to-and) - [user3529361](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11941/user3529361)
  2 total votes, 0 question votes, 5 answers, 173 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How can an advanced civilization harvest energy from an x-ray binary?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22920/how-can-an-advanced-civilization-harvest-energy-from-an-x-ray-binary) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  2 total votes, 2 question votes, 0 answers, 45 views
- [Can we use CME or solar flare to power spacecraft?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23141/can-we-use-cme-or-solar-flare-to-power-spacecraft) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  2 total votes, 1 question votes, 1 answers, 26 views
- [Would the moon doom a particle accelerator attached to the ISS?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22849/would-the-moon-doom-a-particle-accelerator-attached-to-the-iss) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  0 total votes, 0 question votes, 1 answers, 94 views
- [Shoot for the moon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23150/shoot-for-the-moon) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  -1 total votes, -3 question votes, 2 answers, 79 views
  [image: Shot Down (bronze badge): total score of less than 0 on question and answers]