# Fortnightly topic challenge #15: Worldbuilding-Process

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our fifteenth topic challenge!

Topic: [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process)

Dates: 31 August - 14 September

Proposed by:

[image]

> Our stack exchange is about building worlds. We have a lot of great questions with great ideas but it would be interesting to have tips or techniques to help us build better worlds.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Comment: Yay ! but the other challenge had several hours to go before closing.

Comment: @Vincent Oops! *Shhh. . .* Maybe no one will notice. . . 20 minutes to go, though - I think.

Comment: @Vincent What hour do these challenges end? I assumed midnight, though I realize now that time zones are an issue, and the posts never specified.

Comment: Eh, so we have a day of overlap.  Special, today only: *two* challenges for your Q&A pleasure!

Comment: @MonicaCellio Didn't it happen before, too? Anyway, if anyone can tie both tags together, I'll be impressed.

Comment: We could have 2 challenges at the same time for one day.  I don't really see a problem, it was just a remark. We do it when we have the time, therefore it's possible that the timing in not perfect. But just don't "close" the other one too early. Someone might have a question they haven't ha the time to post yet. You know how they are, these last minute people.

Comment: Can I suggest that you include the tag description text directly in these challenge questions?  I know it's fairly obvious, and you can get to it with a couple of clicks, but it would still be nice for it to be immediately available.

Comment: @DanSmolinske Sure. I'll ask ArtOfCode to include that in the generator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This challenge generated 19 questions and 96 answers, for an average of 5.05 answers per question.

#### Posts

- [How can I make my languages structurally less like English?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23765/how-can-i-make-my-languages-structurally-less-like-english) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  175 total votes, 42 question votes, 21 answers, 6057 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Idea Generation (gold badge): 20 answers on your question] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [How can I make a shared world less restrictive?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23861/how-can-i-make-a-shared-world-less-restrictive) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  69 total votes, 18 question votes, 9 answers, 2156 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Creating a realistic world map - Countries Borders](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23820/creating-a-realistic-world-map-countries-borders) - [bilbo_pingouin](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9685/bilbo-pingouin)
  33 total votes, 12 question votes, 4 answers, 1384 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [How to approach the creation of fairy-tale world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/24006/how-to-approach-the-creation-of-fairy-tale-world) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  33 total votes, 7 question votes, 7 answers, 616 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How do I make the political evolution of my world believable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23811/how-do-i-make-the-political-evolution-of-my-world-believable) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  31 total votes, 14 question votes, 6 answers, 1254 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Creating a realistic world - Spreading religions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25478/creating-a-realistic-world-spreading-religions) - [Vincent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/147/vincent)
  26 total votes, 11 question votes, 6 answers, 161 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Creating a realistic world - Spreading languages](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25396/creating-a-realistic-world-spreading-languages) - [Vincent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/147/vincent)
  22 total votes, 6 question votes, 5 answers, 135 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Creating a realistic world map - Vegetation/Biomes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23941/creating-a-realistic-world-map-vegetation-biomes) - [Vincent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/147/vincent)
  20 total votes, 10 question votes, 1 answers, 103 views
- [Methods for filling in your world - Political Entities](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23934/methods-for-filling-in-your-world-political-entities) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  20 total votes, 8 question votes, 3 answers, 385 views
- [How can I make the cultural evolution of my world believable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/24042/how-can-i-make-the-cultural-evolution-of-my-world-believable) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  17 total votes, 13 question votes, 2 answers, 102 views
- [How can I replicate language evolution?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25228/how-can-i-replicate-language-evolution) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  16 total votes, 9 question votes, 2 answers, 125 views
- [Methods for filling in your world - non-state actors](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25358/methods-for-filling-in-your-world-non-state-actors) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  14 total votes, 4 question votes, 7 answers, 329 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Creating a realistic world map - Mineralogy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25084/creating-a-realistic-world-map-mineralogy) - [Vincent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/147/vincent)
  13 total votes, 9 question votes, 2 answers, 155 views
- [Creating a realistic world - Governments](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25524/creating-a-realistic-world-governments) - [Vincent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/147/vincent)
  13 total votes, 5 question votes, 5 answers, 119 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Methods for filling in your world - Brigands, Bandits, Rebels and Thieves](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25450/methods-for-filling-in-your-world-brigands-bandits-rebels-and-thieves) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  13 total votes, 7 question votes, 6 answers, 246 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Creating a realistic world map - Fuel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/creating-a-realistic-world-map-fuel) - [Vincent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/147/vincent)
  8 total votes, 5 question votes, 1 answers, 81 views
- [How do you not lose your mind when thinking about Structural Politics?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23819/how-do-you-not-lose-your-mind-when-thinking-about-structural-politics) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  6 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 158 views
- [How to create social structures?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25419/how-to-create-social-structures) - [SpaceLizard](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9601/spacelizard)
  6 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 96 views
- [What is world building?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25185/what-is-world-building) - [Baby Aaron](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13356/baby-aaron)
  -1 total votes, -3 question votes, 1 answers, 34 views
  [image: Shot Down (bronze badge): total score of less than 0 on question and answers]