# Fortnightly topic challenge #16: Warfare

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our sixteenth topic challenge!

Topic: [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare)

Dates: 14 September - 28 September

Proposed by:

[image]

> Who doesn't like a nice war? Let's challenge the myth that it never changes!

I love the smell of gunpowder in the morning.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Comment: This should be interesting.  I am thinking of weaponizing a frog brigade.

Comment: @James You mean like in [this question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22426/lets-weaponize-frogs)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This challenge generated 27 questions and 171 answers, for an average of 6.33 answers per question.

#### Posts

- [How would a war between immortals be fought?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25658/how-would-a-war-between-immortals-be-fought) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  317 total votes, 47 question votes, 25 answers, 12241 views
  [image: Vote Hunter (gold badge): over 200 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Idea Generation (gold badge): 20 answers on your question] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [What good are herbivores in an animal army?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25724/what-good-are-herbivores-in-an-animal-army) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  313 total votes, 32 question votes, 16 answers, 7711 views
  [image: Vote Hunter (gold badge): over 200 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Do Surface Warships Have a Future?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26138/do-surface-warships-have-a-future) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  58 total votes, 12 question votes, 12 answers, 2352 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [How powerful do I make my mages to inspire trench warfare?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25872/how-powerful-do-i-make-my-mages-to-inspire-trench-warfare) - [DaaaahWhoosh](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6507/daaaahwhoosh)
  51 total votes, 9 question votes, 8 answers, 2090 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Forest rebels and the animal brigade](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25715/forest-rebels-and-the-animal-brigade) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  43 total votes, 14 question votes, 2 answers, 771 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers]
- [How to defend ourselves against unknown aliens?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26046/how-to-defend-ourselves-against-unknown-aliens) - [Tyrabel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11079/tyrabel)
  34 total votes, 7 question votes, 10 answers, 361 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Creating super soldiers by removing emotion (singular)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25816/creating-super-soldiers-by-removing-emotion-singular) - [Jake](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2092/jake)
  27 total votes, 15 question votes, 10 answers, 1523 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Do powerful lasers mean no aircraft is safe?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/do-powerful-lasers-mean-no-aircraft-is-safe) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  22 total votes, 9 question votes, 8 answers, 646 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Military Tank for an Interstellar War](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25611/military-tank-for-an-interstellar-war) - [moran](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10738/moran)
  18 total votes, 3 question votes, 9 answers, 310 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What non-metallic materials would allow making guns and bullets?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26155/what-non-metallic-materials-would-allow-making-guns-and-bullets) - [ASCIIThenANSI](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9498/asciithenansi)
  18 total votes, 5 question votes, 6 answers, 747 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Military Logistics: F' 'em and Feed them Beans!](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25756/military-logistics-f-em-and-feed-them-beans) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  16 total votes, 4 question votes, 7 answers, 291 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What should be considered for creating a Professional Army in a medieval based society?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25817/what-should-be-considered-for-creating-a-professional-army-in-a-medieval-based-s) - [Dynas](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11327/dynas)
  15 total votes, 6 question votes, 4 answers, 201 views
- [What kind of attire would covert ops actually wear?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25764/what-kind-of-attire-would-covert-ops-actually-wear) - [Llama_guy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11564/llama-guy)
  13 total votes, 7 question votes, 5 answers, 241 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How to make Varus win the battle of the Teutoburg Forest?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25654/how-to-make-varus-win-the-battle-of-the-teutoburg-forest) - [celtschk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/98/celtschk)
  12 total votes, 5 question votes, 2 answers, 138 views
- [How would military tactics differ if we primarily used android soldiers?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26313/how-would-military-tactics-differ-if-we-primarily-used-android-soldiers) - [DJMethaneMan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6799/djmethaneman)
  12 total votes, 4 question votes, 5 answers, 158 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- ["The American British Colonies Support Great Britain in the War Effort!"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25685/the-american-british-colonies-support-great-britain-in-the-war-effort) - [Dopapp](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13556/dopapp)
  11 total votes, 7 question votes, 4 answers, 250 views
- [What would out-of-water warfare look like for underwater people?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25648/what-would-out-of-water-warfare-look-like-for-underwater-people) - [Mikey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey)
  10 total votes, 8 question votes, 2 answers, 127 views
- [Battles in space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25896/battles-in-space) - [Jimmery](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/320/jimmery)
  7 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 96 views
- [War's just a [meta]game, son!](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26279/wars-just-a-metagame-son) - [Cort Ammon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2252/cort-ammon)
  7 total votes, 4 question votes, 4 answers, 162 views
- [How would the widespread creation and use of androids affect weaponry?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26300/how-would-the-widespread-creation-and-use-of-androids-affect-weaponry) - [DJMethaneMan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6799/djmethaneman)
  7 total votes, 3 question votes, 3 answers, 89 views
- [Eco-Terrorism in Cyberpunk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25760/eco-terrorism-in-cyberpunk) - [bilbo_pingouin](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9685/bilbo-pingouin)
  7 total votes, 1 question votes, 3 answers, 123 views
- [Other than surprise, what is our chief weapon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26380/other-than-surprise-what-is-our-chief-weapon) - [Dan Smolinske](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/5002/dan-smolinske)
  7 total votes, 3 question votes, 5 answers, 115 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Can a medieval age sub turn the tides of war?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26408/can-a-medieval-age-sub-turn-the-tides-of-war) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  7 total votes, 3 question votes, 4 answers, 99 views
- [Command and control structures in a war where time-travel is possible](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26339/command-and-control-structures-in-a-war-where-time-travel-is-possible) - [Joe Bloggs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9887/joe-bloggs)
  6 total votes, 5 question votes, 2 answers, 133 views
- [Who would win? Dinosaurs vs Mammals](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25783/who-would-win-dinosaurs-vs-mammals) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 5 answers, 226 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How to deal with our giant?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26479/how-to-deal-with-our-giant) - [Liath](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/18/liath)
  5 total votes, 3 question votes, 4 answers, 94 views
- [Zombies, attrition warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26149/zombies-attrition-warfare) - [Vincent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/147/vincent)
  3 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 139 views

Comment: love the format!