# Fortnightly topic challenge #17: Moons

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our seventeenth topic challenge!

Topic: [moons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moons)

Dates: 28 September - 12 October

Proposed by:

[image]

> We've seen a lot of questions here about planets and the people on them, but the existence or nonexistence of moons is also a very important factor to the planet, influencing factors such as tides.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Comment: I'm tempted to ask a question under this tag about the Death Star. Just to see what people say.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Your question is not about [moons] voting to close as off topic =P

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - in that case, one might ask about the effects of having a plumber in one's house bending down and exposing his backside.

Comment: @Culyx suggest migration to SpaceStations.SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This challenge generated 32 questions and 100 answers, for an average of 3.13 answers per question.

#### Posts

- [Moons of Moons of Moons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26773/moons-of-moons-of-moons) - [Varrick](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11087/varrick)
  89 total votes, 25 question votes, 4 answers, 4273 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [How big can a moon be where you can jump to its planet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26663/how-big-can-a-moon-be-where-you-can-jump-to-its-planet) - [DaaaahWhoosh](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6507/daaaahwhoosh)
  81 total votes, 16 question votes, 7 answers, 4899 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [That's no moon! It's a space station! How big can a space ship be before it collapses on itself?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27185/thats-no-moon-its-a-space-station-how-big-can-a-space-ship-be-before-it-coll) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  31 total votes, 12 question votes, 3 answers, 1323 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Murder on the Moon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26927/murder-on-the-moon) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  27 total votes, 2 question votes, 6 answers, 802 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How will the world react if our moon turns into black hole?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26730/how-will-the-world-react-if-our-moon-turns-into-black-hole) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  26 total votes, 6 question votes, 9 answers, 529 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Effects on the Earth if the moon was at 1/10th current distance?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27062/effects-on-the-earth-if-the-moon-was-at-1-10th-current-distance) - [DaaaahWhoosh](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6507/daaaahwhoosh)
  23 total votes, 8 question votes, 3 answers, 1233 views
- [How to get rid of moon stations?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27189/how-to-get-rid-of-moon-stations) - [Angelo Fuchs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/14037/angelo-fuchs)
  22 total votes, 5 question votes, 5 answers, 116 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How Do We Keep The Moon From Eating The World?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27082/how-do-we-keep-the-moon-from-eating-the-world) - [Dan Smolinske](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/5002/dan-smolinske)
  21 total votes, 7 question votes, 3 answers, 574 views
- [Why build space habitats on/within moons?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26672/why-build-space-habitats-on-within-moons) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  19 total votes, 7 question votes, 5 answers, 623 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What does my moon colony need?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26561/what-does-my-moon-colony-need) - [Dan Smolinske](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/5002/dan-smolinske)
  15 total votes, 7 question votes, 5 answers, 217 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Get/Keep Air on the Moon!](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26527/get-keep-air-on-the-moon) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  15 total votes, 7 question votes, 5 answers, 264 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Can a robot experience an identity crisis (which is not by design)?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27134/can-a-robot-experience-an-identity-crisis-which-is-not-by-design) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  14 total votes, 4 question votes, 4 answers, 127 views
- [What is the minimum level of technology to enable interlunar civilization?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/what-is-the-minimum-level-of-technology-to-enable-interlunar-civilization) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  13 total votes, 6 question votes, 1 answers, 301 views
- [RFP: Put me on the moon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26791/rfp-put-me-on-the-moon) - [Hannover Fist](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10970/hannover-fist)
  10 total votes, 3 question votes, 4 answers, 143 views
- [Moon composed of optical material](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26595/moon-composed-of-optical-material) - [Culyx](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/366/culyx)
  10 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 75 views
- [With what precision & timing can we send a missile to strike the moon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27254/with-what-precision-timing-can-we-send-a-missile-to-strike-the-moon) - [Mikey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey)
  9 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 120 views
- [How could I make the moon appear larger?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26717/how-could-i-make-the-moon-appear-larger) - [Lord of Eden](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/lord-of-eden)
  9 total votes, 4 question votes, 3 answers, 123 views
- [What kinds of stories would people from a forest moon tell about their "moon"?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26613/what-kinds-of-stories-would-people-from-a-forest-moon-tell-about-their-moon) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  9 total votes, 6 question votes, 2 answers, 77 views
- [Can we build a space elevator on the Moon with present technology?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26578/can-we-build-a-space-elevator-on-the-moon-with-present-technology) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  8 total votes, 5 question votes, 2 answers, 165 views
- [Largest stable object in "daily" orbit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26896/largest-stable-object-in-daily-orbit) - [Michael Richardson](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13484/michael-richardson)
  7 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 47 views
- [How to convince King Arthur you have just returned from the Moon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26712/how-to-convince-king-arthur-you-have-just-returned-from-the-moon) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  7 total votes, 3 question votes, 4 answers, 141 views
- [How to blanket moon with a permanent atmosphere?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26639/how-to-blanket-moon-with-a-permanent-atmosphere) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  7 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 99 views
- [Making doomsayers right - a moon(s), planet alignment that matters](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26609/making-doomsayers-right-an-eclipse-that-matters) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  7 total votes, 6 question votes, 3 answers, 93 views
- [Is a moon inside a hollow Earth possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27449/is-a-moon-inside-a-hollow-earth-possible) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 38 views
- [What would a space elevator on the moon be made out of?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27019/what-would-a-space-elevator-on-the-moon-be-made-out-of) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 122 views
- [What is the most effective way to build road on Mars and Moon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26826/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-build-road-on-mars-and-moon) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  5 total votes, 3 question votes, 2 answers, 86 views
- [How can you make a stable configuration including a moon that has a moon?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26634/how-can-you-make-a-stable-configuration-including-a-moon-that-has-a-moon) - [Monica Cellio](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/28/monica-cellio)
  4 total votes, 3 question votes, 1 answers, 475 views
- [Seasons/Months on a Habitable Gas Giant Moon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26816/seasons-months-on-a-habitable-gas-giant-moon) - [Midwinter Sun](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/14177/midwinter-sun)
  1 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 81 views
- [How primitive should the alien technology be to exchange knowledge and culture?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27376/how-primitive-should-the-alien-technology-be-to-exchange-knowledge-and-culture) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  -1 total votes, -2 question votes, 2 answers, 35 views
  [image: Shot Down (bronze badge): total score of less than 0 on question and answers]
- [Spacecraft pulled by the moon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26704/spacecraft-pulled-by-the-moon) - [king of panes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13492/king-of-panes)
  -1 total votes, -2 question votes, 2 answers, 41 views
  [image: Shot Down (bronze badge): total score of less than 0 on question and answers]
- [Shall the Moon be Bigger or Closer?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26909/shall-the-moon-be-bigger-or-closer) - [JohnWDailey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10274/johnwdailey)
  -2 total votes, -4 question votes, 1 answers, 40 views
  [image: Shot Down (bronze badge): total score of less than 0 on question and answers]
- https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26630/the-moon-vs-the-earth-no-longer-moving - [Feidhelm](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13506/feidhelm)
  -3 total votes, -3 question votes, 1 answers, 93 views
  [image: Shot Down (bronze badge): total score of less than 0 on question and answers]

Comment: Wow, I did not expect to get second place. That said, there still aren't many answers to that question that satisfy the [tag:hard-science] tag. Either way, this challenge was a lot more interesting than I thought it was going to be.