# Fortnightly topic challenge #18: Architecture

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our eighteenth topic challenge!

Topic: [architecture](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture)

Dates: 12 October - 26 October

Proposed by:

[image]

> We spend so much time building entire worlds that we often forget about building smaller things.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Comment: If the first 24 hours is anything to go by, this challenge doesn't seem to be a very popular one.

Comment: Maybe people are just taking more time to ask better quality answers ;)

Comment: @DoubleDouble How does one ask an answer, of any quality?

Comment: @Frostfyre haha.. meant question of course >< didn't even notice that. (And, since you asked, "what is Jeopardy?")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This challenge generated 18 questions and 67 answers, for an average of 3.72 answers per question. A total of 4635 reputation was handed out as a result of this challenge.

#### Posts

- [Architecture of the perfect zombie apocalypse refuge](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28053/architecture-of-the-perfect-zombie-apocalypse-refuge) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  297 total votes, 51 question votes, 16 answers, 6333 views
  [image: Vote Hunter (gold badge): over 200 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [I would like a levitating temple on a mountain. Hand-wave free...ish](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27627/i-would-like-a-levitating-temple-on-a-mountain-hand-wave-free-ish) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  40 total votes, 10 question votes, 8 answers, 211 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Architectural encoding of maps](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27960/architectural-encoding-of-maps) - [Ville Niemi](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3434/ville-niemi)
  29 total votes, 11 question votes, 5 answers, 210 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Medieval low-energy houses](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27665/medieval-low-energy-houses) - [celtschk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/98/celtschk)
  24 total votes, 8 question votes, 5 answers, 228 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Gravity and Architecture](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27539/gravity-and-architecture) - [Frostfyre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6986/frostfyre)
  21 total votes, 11 question votes, 2 answers, 279 views
- [How would a city of AI be built?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27458/how-would-a-city-of-ai-be-built) - [DaaaahWhoosh](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6507/daaaahwhoosh)
  20 total votes, 8 question votes, 5 answers, 170 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What are some major architectural designs in spaceships for aquatic beings](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27761/what-are-some-major-architectural-designs-in-spaceships-for-aquatic-beings) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  18 total votes, 10 question votes, 4 answers, 125 views
- [What should centaur dwellings look like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27567/what-should-centaur-dwellings-look-like) - [Monica Cellio](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/28/monica-cellio)
  15 total votes, 9 question votes, 1 answers, 129 views
- [Hair based architecture](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27958/hair-based-architecture) - [Ville Niemi](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3434/ville-niemi)
  14 total votes, 11 question votes, 1 answers, 189 views
- [What are some major architectural designs that would be in spaceships for flighted beings?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27618/what-are-some-major-architectural-designs-that-would-be-in-spaceships-for-flight) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  14 total votes, 5 question votes, 5 answers, 413 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [The cultural flow of Architecture](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27850/the-cultural-flow-of-architecture) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  13 total votes, 7 question votes, 3 answers, 235 views
- [What's the largest building you could build on the world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27557/whats-the-largest-building-you-could-build-on-the-world) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  12 total votes, 3 question votes, 5 answers, 163 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How deep should our colony be on the Moon/Mars?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27933/how-deep-should-our-colony-be-on-the-moon-mars) - [Mikey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey)
  7 total votes, 3 question votes, 1 answers, 121 views
- [If one of the spatial dimensions wrapped around, how would architecture be different?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27821/if-one-of-the-spatial-dimensions-wrapped-around-how-would-architecture-be-diffe) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  6 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 84 views
- [What would the architecture be like in an alternate history where Mexico was colonized by China?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28117/what-would-the-architecture-be-like-in-an-alternate-history-where-mexico-was-col) - [user24353](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/12213/user24353)
  6 total votes, 3 question votes, 1 answers, 82 views
- [How will cities be transformed after hover cars become common?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27853/how-will-cities-be-transformed-after-hover-cars-become-common) - [Relix](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2081/relix)
  3 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 63 views
- [Could a historic society live on another world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27654/could-a-historic-society-live-on-another-world) - [ArtOfCode](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2685/artofcode)
  2 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 66 views
- [If one of the spatial dimensions *not* perpendicular to gravity wrapped around, how would architecture be different?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27875/if-one-of-the-spatial-dimensions-not-perpendicular-to-gravity-wrapped-around) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  0 total votes, 0 question votes, 0 answers, 38 views

Comment: This post generated by @ArtOfCode 's [excellent generator](http://jenkinsstuff.bl.ee/challenge/#)