# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #19: Politics

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our nineteenth topic challenge!

Topic: [politics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics)

Dates: 26 Oct - 9 Nov

Proposed by:

[image]

> There has already been discussion of how to ask questions about the delicate subject of religion. Politics is another subject often avoided in everyday conversation to avoid potential offense. Perhaps a couple of weeks of questions would help test what is acceptable and on topic?

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Comment: Well this should be entertaining...

Comment: Mistakes were made with those dates...

Comment: @ArtOfCode Yes they were, good catch. I guess I was more worried about ending the last challenge than starting the new one, though it looks like you made some edits to that post as well.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh My only edit there was to apply the most recent update to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This challenge generated 22 questions and 117 answers, for an average of 5.32 answers per question. A total of 6235 reputation was handed out as a result of this challenge.

#### Posts

- [What's the most likely "post democracy" form of political government?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28980/whats-the-most-likely-post-democracy-form-of-political-government) - [Tim B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b)
  263 total votes, 60 question votes, 23 answers, 8434 views
  [image: Vote Hunter (gold badge): over 200 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Idea Generation (gold badge): 20 answers on your question] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [How would government change if everyone died by the age of 25?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29199/how-would-government-change-if-everyone-died-by-the-age-of-25) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  178 total votes, 41 question votes, 21 answers, 6175 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Idea Generation (gold badge): 20 answers on your question] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Would Earth try to keep extra-planetary colonies dependent on them for financial gain and political power?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28569/would-earth-try-to-keep-extra-planetary-colonies-dependent-on-them-for-financial) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  71 total votes, 19 question votes, 10 answers, 2991 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Medieval politics with fantasy races](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28573/medieval-politics-with-fantasy-races) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  30 total votes, 15 question votes, 4 answers, 223 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers]
- [How would political power shift without upheaveal?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/how-would-political-power-shift-without-upheaveal) - [DonyorM](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/81/donyorm)
  22 total votes, 5 question votes, 6 answers, 420 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How to make elections magic-proof?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28805/how-to-make-elections-magic-proof) - [celtschk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/98/celtschk)
  17 total votes, 7 question votes, 4 answers, 304 views
- [How will uploaded personalities be represented in a government?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28624/how-will-uploaded-personalities-be-represented-in-a-government) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  17 total votes, 6 question votes, 5 answers, 175 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Would an A.I. make a good politician?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28636/would-a-i-make-a-good-politician) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  15 total votes, 8 question votes, 6 answers, 141 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What would be the most viable form of government for the first space colonies?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28642/what-would-be-the-most-viable-form-of-government-for-the-first-space-colonies) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  15 total votes, 5 question votes, 4 answers, 200 views
- [Political ramifications of long-lived humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28725/political-ramifications-of-long-lived-humans) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  13 total votes, 6 question votes, 3 answers, 114 views
- [How can a dynasty of immortals be overthrown?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28993/how-can-a-dynasty-of-immortals-be-overthrown) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  12 total votes, 5 question votes, 2 answers, 331 views
- [Result of a goverment where extra votes can be bought, earned, or lost?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29016/result-of-a-goverment-where-extra-votes-can-be-bought-earned-or-lost) - [dsollen](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/4857/dsollen)
  11 total votes, 4 question votes, 5 answers, 155 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How does the law treat uploaded personalities?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28594/how-does-the-law-treat-uploaded-personalities) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  11 total votes, 7 question votes, 2 answers, 54 views
- [How might digital intellectual disability be dealt with by society?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28611/how-might-digital-intellectual-disability-be-dealt-with-by-society) - [Samuel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3202/samuel)
  11 total votes, 6 question votes, 2 answers, 90 views
- [Would Lunar and Martian Colonists Retain a Global Government?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29070/would-lunar-and-martian-colonists-retain-a-global-government) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  9 total votes, 2 question votes, 3 answers, 100 views
- [What can be the main political reason behind mass cloning of soldiers?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28537/what-can-be-the-main-political-reason-behind-mass-cloning-of-soldiers) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  9 total votes, 4 question votes, 4 answers, 98 views
- [Tyrant ruled kingdom surrounded by wilderness?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29010/tyrant-ruled-kingdom-surrounded-by-wilderness) - [BHustus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/15006/bhustus)
  9 total votes, 7 question votes, 4 answers, 161 views
- [What is a good political reason for every spacecraft design to come with self destruct sequence?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28521/what-is-a-good-political-reason-for-every-spacecraft-design-to-come-with-self-de) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  8 total votes, 3 question votes, 2 answers, 98 views
- [Intelligent Animal Politics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28553/intelligent-animal-politics) - [C. VanHorn](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13707/c-vanhorn)
  4 total votes, 4 question votes, 2 answers, 113 views
- [How to convince your population to get to war?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28783/how-to-convince-your-population-to-get-to-war) - [bilbo_pingouin](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9685/bilbo-pingouin)
  4 total votes, 2 question votes, 3 answers, 96 views
- [Politics in an A.I. Society Without Humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28529/politics-in-an-a-i-society-without-humans) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  1 total votes, -2 question votes, 2 answers, 58 views
- [What sort of government might very long-lived humans form with normal humans?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29154/what-sort-of-government-might-very-long-lived-humans-form-with-normal-humans) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  1 total votes, 1 question votes, 0 answers, 43 views