# Fortnightly challenge # 20: Language

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our twentieth topic challenge!

Topic: [language](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)

Dates: 9 Nov - 23 Nov

Proposed by:

[image]

> Because language influences and is influenced by culture, religion, history, geography, and much more. I would love to see more questions exploring these nuances.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

For a list of past topics, or to propose new topics go here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Answer (score 3):

This challenge generated 19 questions and 114 answers, for an average of 6.00 answers per question. A total of 6080 reputation was handed out as a result of this challenge.

#### Posts

- [In an atheist alien society where bodily functions (reproduction and waste elimination) are not taboo what would be used to curse?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/in-an-atheist-alien-society-where-bodily-functions-reproduction-and-waste-elimi) - [Tim B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b)
  255 total votes, 42 question votes, 18 answers, 9511 views
  [image: Vote Hunter (gold badge): over 200 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [What language would the Anglo-French Empire use?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29720/what-language-would-the-anglo-french-empire-use) - [Philip Rowlands](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7076/philip-rowlands)
  70 total votes, 10 question votes, 11 answers, 1428 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Why would a language based solely on volume develop?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29885/why-would-a-language-based-solely-on-volume-develop) - [jimsug](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13869/jimsug)
  58 total votes, 12 question votes, 7 answers, 2299 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Can a single language have two separate dialects spoken in a single location?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29447/can-a-single-language-have-two-separate-dialects-spoken-in-a-single-location) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  58 total votes, 8 question votes, 14 answers, 1449 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How do I keep a language shared by two separate peoples, static for as long as possible? The lower tech-complexity the better?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29908/how-do-i-keep-a-language-shared-by-two-separate-peoples-static-for-as-long-as-p) - [Malandy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6812/malandy)
  56 total votes, 10 question votes, 10 answers, 1798 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Would a common language develop in a fantasy world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29491/would-a-common-language-develop-in-a-fantasy-world) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  39 total votes, 12 question votes, 11 answers, 1767 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Grammar for a species that communicates via hallucinations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29881/grammar-for-a-species-that-communicates-via-hallucinations) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  21 total votes, 12 question votes, 6 answers, 351 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Will spoken language become obsolete with advances in technology?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29632/will-spoken-language-become-obsolete-with-advances-in-technology) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  20 total votes, 8 question votes, 7 answers, 667 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What language would droids use to communicate with each other?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29661/what-language-would-droids-use-to-communicate-with-each-other) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  20 total votes, 5 question votes, 4 answers, 526 views
- [Is it possible for a language/method of passing information based purely on touch to develop?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29518/is-it-possible-for-a-language-method-of-passing-information-based-purely-on-touc) - [Joe Bloggs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9887/joe-bloggs)
  15 total votes, 6 question votes, 3 answers, 330 views
- [What would a gesture-based language look like in the absence of a spoken language?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29653/what-would-a-gesture-based-language-look-like-in-the-absence-of-a-spoken-languag) - [Monica Cellio](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/28/monica-cellio)
  15 total votes, 4 question votes, 3 answers, 216 views
- [How to explain something like a universal translator](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29727/how-to-explain-something-like-a-universal-translator) - [AndyD273](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6751/andyd273)
  13 total votes, 5 question votes, 4 answers, 141 views
- [What are ways plants might be communicating with one another without people realizing it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29737/what-are-ways-plants-might-be-communicating-with-one-another-without-people-real) - [DoubleDouble](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2138/doubledouble)
  12 total votes, 6 question votes, 3 answers, 91 views
- [Developing Counting Systems](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29471/developing-counting-systems) - [PipperChip](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7/pipperchip)
  7 total votes, 3 question votes, 5 answers, 197 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Would communication lag stop language developing in a space-borne race?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/would-communication-lag-stop-language-developing-in-a-space-borne-race) - [Joe Bloggs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9887/joe-bloggs)
  7 total votes, 4 question votes, 1 answers, 99 views
- [Possible language changes of a suddenly isolated group](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30220/possible-language-changes-of-a-suddenly-isolated-group) - [Wick](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/15016/wick)
  7 total votes, 3 question votes, 1 answers, 47 views
- [Do intelligent organisms evolved to communicate only through scent have a language?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29684/do-intelligent-organisms-evolved-to-communicate-only-through-scent-have-a-langua) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 34 views
- [Language problems for time travelers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29511/language-problems-for-time-travelers) - [Crissov](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11787/crissov)
  5 total votes, 3 question votes, 3 answers, 109 views
- [Abstract conversation on an interspecies level](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30207/abstract-conversation-on-an-interspecies-level) - [ban_lonely_days](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/15501/ban-lonely-days)
  3 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 82 views