# Fortnightly challenge # 21: Underwater

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our 21st topic challenge!

Topic: [underwater](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underwater)

Dates: 25 Nov - 7 Dec

Proposed by:

[image]

> There's a whole 'nother world underneath the oceans. Mermaids and mermen are the typical citizens, in Earth lore, but they're not the only ones there. I can see some creative civilizations and creatures coming out of a topic challenge focused on this.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Comment: I just realised that no one changed it...

Comment: Would the "world underneath the oceans" be the crust/mantle/core? Or are we expecting high-magic environments where the oceans float?

Comment: Bahaha...I just glanced at the featured box and thought it said "underwear," I spent the whole time in the shower trying to think if I had any questions or expertise for answers on underwear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This challenge generated 25 questions and 80 answers, for an average of 3.20 answers per question. A total of 4490 reputation was handed out as a result of this challenge.

#### Posts

- [An underwater creature that could take down a boat](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30662/an-underwater-creature-that-could-take-down-a-boat) - [Mike.C.Ford](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8312/mike-c-ford)
  157 total votes, 22 question votes, 13 answers, 6365 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [How deep can the ocean plausibly be?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30513/how-deep-can-the-ocean-plausibly-be) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  92 total votes, 26 question votes, 6 answers, 3914 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [How do mermaids perform major surgical procedure underwater?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30738/how-do-mermaids-perform-major-surgical-procedure-underwater) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  66 total votes, 14 question votes, 3 answers, 3673 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Mermaid architecture](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/mermaid-architecture) - [bilbo_pingouin](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9685/bilbo-pingouin)
  24 total votes, 6 question votes, 5 answers, 105 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How big can the leviathan and kraken really be?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30480/how-big-can-the-leviathan-and-kraken-really-be) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  19 total votes, 9 question votes, 2 answers, 417 views
- [What would make good clothing for an underwater species?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30843/what-would-make-good-clothing-for-an-underwater-species) - [DoubleDouble](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2138/doubledouble)
  17 total votes, 6 question votes, 5 answers, 146 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Do mermaids lay eggs underwater or give birth to live young?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30645/do-mermaids-lay-eggs-underwater-or-give-birth-to-live-young) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  16 total votes, 4 question votes, 3 answers, 358 views
- [How could an underwater civilization develop electricity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30927/how-could-an-underwater-civilization-develop-electricity) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  15 total votes, 8 question votes, 3 answers, 371 views
- [Low-tech Underwater Weaponry](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30561/low-tech-underwater-weaponry) - [Tim B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b)
  14 total votes, 4 question votes, 2 answers, 178 views
- [What adaptations would a water-dwelling species need to survive by primarily hunting pre-industrial humans?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30820/what-adaptations-would-a-water-dwelling-species-need-to-survive-by-primarily-hun) - [DJMethaneMan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6799/djmethaneman)
  11 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 400 views
- [Save London From a Sudden Glacial Melting?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30762/save-london-from-a-sudden-glacial-melting) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  11 total votes, 5 question votes, 1 answers, 72 views
- [Does mermaid evolution come with buoyancy control?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30699/does-mermaid-evolution-come-with-buoyancy-control) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  10 total votes, 3 question votes, 1 answers, 67 views
- [Cephalopods Inherit the World](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30690/cephalopods-inherit-the-world) - [PipperChip](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7/pipperchip)
  10 total votes, 3 question votes, 5 answers, 171 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What modifications are needed for my sea creature to able to hold its breath for weeks?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30613/what-modifications-are-needed-for-my-sea-creature-to-able-to-hold-its-breath-for) - [Mikey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey)
  10 total votes, 3 question votes, 5 answers, 224 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How do mermaids' ears work?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30706/how-do-mermaids-ears-work) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  9 total votes, 4 question votes, 2 answers, 128 views
- [How to explain a mermaid's tail morphing into legs and vice versa?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30707/how-to-explain-mermaids-tail-morphing-into-legs-and-vice-versa) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  8 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 231 views
- [How do mermaids map ocean currents?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30744/how-do-mermaids-map-ocean-currents) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  6 total votes, 4 question votes, 1 answers, 64 views
- [What happened when my scientist drilled a hole through Europa's "crust"?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30837/what-happened-when-my-scientist-drilled-a-hole-through-europas-crust) - [Mikey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey)
  5 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 90 views
- [Would an average seawater mermaid be any larger than its freshwater counterparts?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30702/would-an-average-seawater-mermaid-be-any-larger-than-its-freshwater-counterparts) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  5 total votes, 4 question votes, 2 answers, 92 views
- [What might mini submersible dogfights be like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30680/what-might-mini-submersible-dogfights-be-like) - [cobaltduck](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10851/cobaltduck)
  4 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 89 views
- [How mermaids watch news live on TV underwater if conductivity of sea water affect electromagnetic signal?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30733/how-mermaids-watch-news-live-on-tv-underwater-if-conductivity-of-sea-water-affec) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  4 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 158 views
- [Psychology and sociology in my Earth Changing underwater community](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30566/psychology-and-sociology-in-my-earth-changing-underwater-community) - [Joe Bloggs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9887/joe-bloggs)
  3 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 56 views
- [Cartilaginous mermaid or bony mermaid best for adapting underwater?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30704/cartilaginous-mermaid-or-bony-mermaid-best-for-adapting-underwater) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  2 total votes, 2 question votes, 0 answers, 65 views
- [Would future combat submarines come with jet propulsion thruster?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30647/would-future-combat-submarines-come-with-jet-propulsion-thruster) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  0 total votes, -2 question votes, 5 answers, 135 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30669/could-the-water-found-underground-near-the-earths-crust-somehow-find-its-way-on - [Johnny Urbani](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/15661/johnny-urbani)
  -2 total votes, -2 question votes, 1 answers, 39 views
  [image: Shot Down (bronze badge): total score of less than 0 on question and answers]