# A special challenge for the holidays season?

Tags: discussion, challenge

Following some [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25860034#25860034), it might be interesting for the two weeks starting from Dec. 21st to replace our normal challenge by a Santa-related challenge.

We all know that Santa is delivering gifts to all the well behaved kids in the World. Surely there are some interesting questions about it, which could be included in a world.

Some examples of questions have been thrown around in the chat.

What do you say, do you want to have this special challenge as challenge number #23?

Answer (score 1):

I say we [put it to a vote](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges). It'd only take around fourteen upvotes to put a [santa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/santa) tag on the top of the list. If we don't get that many, then either not enough people care about the challenges, or people don't want to talk about Santa for two weeks.

Comment: Ok,  [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2810/9685) it is. I was just fearing that not that many people had a look at the challenge proposals, but let's see.

Comment: My problem isn't that I don't care, but rather I never have any questions that match the challenge topic.