# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #22: Geography

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our twenty-second topic challenge!

Topic: [geography](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography)

Dates: 7 December - 21 December

Proposed by:

[image]

> It occurs to me that geography has an almost limitless number of questions that can be asked and is crucial to building a world...unless you are doing a story in space...

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This challenge generated 8 questions and 20 answers, for an average of 2.50 answers per question. A total of 1230 reputation was handed out as a result of this challenge.

#### Posts

- [How could 1BC Earth speed up communication across vast distances?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-could-1bc-earth-speed-up-communication-across-vast-distances) - [Mikey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey)
  72 total votes, 14 question votes, 6 answers, 820 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [The really really big mountain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31250/the-really-really-big-mountain) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  21 total votes, 8 question votes, 3 answers, 149 views
  [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [What would cause a supermassive plateau that sticks out of the ocean](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31686/what-would-cause-a-supermassive-plateau-that-sticks-out-of-the-ocean) - [Mikey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey)
  18 total votes, 6 question votes, 5 answers, 112 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Could a habitable planet form with no major bodies of water?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31387/could-a-habitable-planet-form-with-no-major-bodies-of-water) - [Hanko Tanks](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/15131/hanko-tanks)
  13 total votes, 6 question votes, 2 answers, 116 views
- [What mathematical function would describe the relationship between two moons?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31369/what-mathematical-function-would-describe-the-relationship-between-two-moons) - [Kay Ellis](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/14210/kay-ellis)
  10 total votes, 5 question votes, 1 answers, 123 views
- [World with only one habitable, off-center quadrasphere/quadrant](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/world-with-only-one-habitable-off-center-quadrasphere-quadrant) - [CAgrippa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/114/cagrippa)
  6 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 121 views
- [Geography in a universe with 4 spatial dimensions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31124/geography-in-a-universe-with-4-spatial-dimensions) - [Monty Wild](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/75/monty-wild)
  3 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 122 views
- [How to create a holy, happy earth without human death?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/how-to-create-a-holy-happy-earth-without-human-death) - [ManirajSS](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16359/manirajss)
  1 total votes, -1 question votes, 1 answers, 70 views