# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #23: Santa

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our twenty third topic challenge!

Topic: [santa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/santa)

Dates: 21 Dec - 4 Jan

Proposed by:

[image]

> Santa Claus is the embodiment of the holidays season. Why not trying to get Santa in our worlds? Or maybe some other elements around Santa (reindeers, elves, etc.).

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Comment: Related: [blog post](https://medium.com/universe-factory/creature-design-santa-claus-946a9caa6e6#.nlidrlo62)

Answer (score 5):

(Below stats also include questions asked in the week before the challenge)

This challenge generated 17 questions and 103 answers, for an average of 6.06 answers per question. A total of 13895 reputation was handed out as a result of this challenge.

#### Posts

- [Santa is Satan, but why?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32086/santa-is-satan-but-why) - [Tim B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b)
  519 total votes, 91 question votes, 16 answers, 16075 views
  [image: Vote Hunter (gold badge): over 200 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [How does Santa protect himself from IP lawsuits?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31987/how-does-santa-protect-himself-from-ip-lawsuits) - [celtschk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/98/celtschk)
  415 total votes, 86 question votes, 16 answers, 10286 views
  [image: Vote Hunter (gold badge): over 200 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [How can the NSA capture Santa Claus?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31520/how-can-the-nsa-capture-santa-claus) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  217 total votes, 58 question votes, 12 answers, 7886 views
  [image: Vote Hunter (gold badge): over 200 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Santa exists. How do we react?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31482/santa-exists-how-do-we-react) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  128 total votes, 35 question votes, 10 answers, 5812 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How does Santa keep the elves from revolting?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31593/how-does-santa-keep-the-elves-from-revolting) - [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
  119 total votes, 34 question votes, 8 answers, 3939 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How do Santa and the reindeer survive delivery night?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32007/how-do-santa-and-the-reindeer-survive-delivery-night) - [Monica Cellio](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/28/monica-cellio)
  54 total votes, 14 question votes, 7 answers, 1663 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What if Santa does not want Norad to track him?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31457/what-if-santa-does-not-want-norad-to-track-him) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  38 total votes, 8 question votes, 9 answers, 1374 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How does Santa avoid Heart Attacks from bad cholesterol?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32230/how-does-santa-avoid-heart-attacks-from-bad-cholesterol) - [Quill](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16035/quill)
  25 total votes, 8 question votes, 7 answers, 523 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How much does Santa's sleigh weigh?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31460/how-much-does-santas-sleigh-weigh) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  15 total votes, 7 question votes, 2 answers, 291 views
- [Santa is a time traveller. How does he not violate casuality?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32132/santa-is-a-time-traveller-how-does-he-not-violate-casuality) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  9 total votes, 9 question votes, 3 answers, 151 views
- [From where will Santa deliver after North Pole melts?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32471/from-where-will-santa-deliver-after-north-pole-melts) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  5 total votes, 0 question votes, 2 answers, 48 views
- [Robotic Micro Assembler Santa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32155/robotic-micro-assembler-santa) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  5 total votes, 4 question votes, 2 answers, 40 views
- [How to heat your house by being naughty](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32381/how-to-heat-your-house-by-being-naughty) - [Erik Philips](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16648/erik-philips)
  5 total votes, -3 question votes, 3 answers, 119 views
- [If Santa can time travel, why does he need elves to make toys?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32157/if-santa-can-time-travel-why-does-he-need-elves-to-make-toys) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 68 views
- [How does Santa afford the materials to make the toys?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32258/how-does-santa-afford-the-materials-to-make-the-toys) - [Quill](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16035/quill)
  4 total votes, 0 question votes, 1 answers, 43 views
- [How can Santa exist when kids are cryogenically grown until adulthood](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32279/how-can-santa-exist-when-kids-are-cryogenically-grown-until-adulthood) - [Quill](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16035/quill)
  2 total votes, 0 question votes, 1 answers, 60 views
- [Can I use my Earth changing invention to help out Santa?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/can-i-use-my-earth-changing-invention-to-help-out-santa) - [Joe Bloggs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9887/joe-bloggs)
  1 total votes, 0 question votes, 2 answers, 99 views

Comment: Can I just point out that this is the *highest* amount of rep handed out for any of the challenges? Closest is #13 (weapons), on 13075. This one also *nearly* beat the record of answers-per-question (again #13, on 4.89).

Comment: @ArtOfCode This one got 6 answers per question, so that is higher surely?

Comment: @TimB I...don't know how I missed that. Must have read 4.88 from some other challenge.

Comment: Well Santa is a click bait, so no surprise there :-)