# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #24: Near Future

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our twenty-fourth topic challenge!

Topic: [near-future](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-future)

Dates: 4 Jan - 18 Jan

Proposed by:

[image]

> Because we don't want to get ahead of ourselves.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Comment: I just realized, I asked a question using this tag earlier today, completely oblivious to the fact that this challenge was starting today. What are the odds?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh, proof that you have psychic powers! ;-)

Comment: He knew you were going to say that.

Answer (score 1):

This challenge generated 10 questions and 54 answers, for an average of 5.40 answers per question. A total of 3470 reputation was handed out as a result of this challenge.

#### Posts

- ["Life post-Singularity", or "How to survive without Instagram"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32829/life-post-singularity-or-how-to-survive-without-instagram) - [SpaceLizard](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9601/spacelizard)
  127 total votes, 31 question votes, 14 answers, 4289 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [How many nanobots can I have in my blood?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32577/how-many-nanobots-can-i-have-in-my-blood) - [DaaaahWhoosh](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6507/daaaahwhoosh)
  118 total votes, 36 question votes, 4 answers, 4821 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [If Venus mission finds life, will we shift our attention from Mars to Venus?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32647/if-venus-mission-finds-life-will-we-shift-our-attention-from-mars-to-venus) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  66 total votes, 17 question votes, 4 answers, 3144 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Apps for our bodies](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33520/apps-for-our-bodies) - [JDługosz](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/885/jd%c5%82ugosz)
  31 total votes, 4 question votes, 7 answers, 720 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How do I make floating ambient light?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33440/how-do-i-make-floating-ambient-light) - [Hanko Tanks](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/15131/hanko-tanks)
  20 total votes, 5 question votes, 7 answers, 515 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [AI tasked with bringing down medical costs? What could possibly go wrong?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33272/ai-tasked-with-bringing-down-medical-costs-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  15 total votes, 6 question votes, 9 answers, 414 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What human-induced disaster could cause permanent fog in an area the size of New York City or larger?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32581/what-human-induced-disaster-could-cause-permanent-fog-in-an-area-the-size-of-new) - [DoubleDouble](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2138/doubledouble)
  11 total votes, 5 question votes, 3 answers, 176 views
- [Societal implications of a 200 year lifespan?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33343/societal-implications-of-a-200-year-lifespan) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  10 total votes, 6 question votes, 3 answers, 171 views
- [Geomagnetic interaction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32564/geomagnetic-interaction) - Kristoffer Jay Martin
  3 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 78 views
- [Would self-flying cars fly?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32899/would-self-flying-cars-fly) - [celtschk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/98/celtschk)
  2 total votes, 0 question votes, 2 answers, 69 views