# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #25: Culture and Society

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our twenty-fifth topic challenge!

Topic(s): [culture](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture)[society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society)

Dates: 18 Jan - 1 Feb

Proposed by:

[image]

> These are separate concepts (I believe we had a meta discussion) but it is also tough to divorce them so I am thinking we combine them into a single challenge.
>   These questions can (and have been) tough to ask but I find very interesting.

Remember to use these tags if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Answer (score 4):

This challenge generated 48 questions and 261 answers, for an average of 5.44 answers per question. A total of >12755 reputation was handed out as a result of this challenge (exact stats pending).

#### Posts

- [Society rules for marriages and love on multigeneration ship](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33662/society-rules-for-marriages-and-love-on-multigeneration-ship) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  190 total votes, 42 question votes, 17 answers, 5670 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [I duplicate the U.S. President. What happens?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34602/i-duplicate-the-u-s-president-what-happens) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  172 total votes, 52 question votes, 9 answers, 7563 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Society expectations to Work for your living](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33696/society-expectations-to-work-for-your-living) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  159 total votes, 38 question votes, 14 answers, 4670 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Is it possible for a religion with >1 billion followers to die out?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33806/is-it-possible-for-a-religion-with-1-billion-followers-to-die-out) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  108 total votes, 23 question votes, 13 answers, 7103 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Benevolent aliens will help us all- on one condition. Can we end all wars?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34599/benevolent-aliens-will-help-us-all-on-one-condition-can-we-end-all-wars) - [Daniel M.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16977/daniel-m)
  105 total votes, 14 question votes, 10 answers, 2880 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Effects of "tax your vote" political system](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34119/effects-of-tax-your-vote-political-system) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  92 total votes, 18 question votes, 11 answers, 2899 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What's the impact of a "cloning" teleporter?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34491/whats-the-impact-of-a-cloning-teleporter) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  85 total votes, 25 question votes, 11 answers, 3425 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Can we have a meaningful cultural exchange with aliens if we never meet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33598/can-we-have-a-meaningful-cultural-exchange-with-aliens-if-we-never-meet) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  64 total votes, 23 question votes, 9 answers, 2323 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Is a medieval country of artists viable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34170/is-a-medieval-country-of-artists-viable) - [bilbo_pingouin](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9685/bilbo-pingouin)
  62 total votes, 15 question votes, 6 answers, 2150 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Taxes weighed by years of military service](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34240/taxes-weighed-by-years-of-military-service) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  54 total votes, 14 question votes, 9 answers, 2077 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Could a world where two neigbouring countries, only one of which uses 'magic', exist?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34802/could-a-world-where-two-neigbouring-countries-only-one-of-which-uses-magic-e) - [L.R.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6410/l-r)
  36 total votes, 7 question votes, 12 answers, 1295 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Cultural norms regarding Law and Order on Generation ship](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34289/cultural-norms-regarding-law-and-order-on-generation-ship) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  33 total votes, 10 question votes, 8 answers, 1022 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Would generation ships encourage a caste system?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33894/would-generation-ships-encourage-a-caste-system) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  25 total votes, 11 question votes, 5 answers, 195 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How would magic affect the subjects taught in school?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33746/how-would-magic-affect-the-subjects-taught-in-school) - [XandarTheZenon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16736/xandarthezenon)
  23 total votes, 9 question votes, 3 answers, 243 views
- [How might a colony treat the arrival of a new generation ship?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33896/how-might-a-colony-treat-the-arrival-of-a-new-generation-ship) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  23 total votes, 6 question votes, 5 answers, 183 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How would a drug cartel claim legitimacy as a government entity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34154/how-would-a-drug-cartel-claim-legitimacy-as-a-government-entity) - [Carlos Danger](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17384/carlos-danger)
  23 total votes, 7 question votes, 3 answers, 168 views
- [Significant day-to-day impact of having eyes on palms of hands?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33716/significant-day-to-day-impact-of-having-eyes-on-palms-of-hands) - [user1717828](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13878/user1717828)
  21 total votes, 5 question votes, 7 answers, 610 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Is it possible for birds to use rudimentary technology to build simple infrastructure and weaponry?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33980/is-it-possible-for-birds-to-use-rudimentary-technology-to-build-simple-infrastru) - [johnny](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17333/johnny)
  21 total votes, 7 question votes, 3 answers, 523 views
- [How would society react to docile zombies?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/how-would-society-react-to-docile-zombies) - [DaaaahWhoosh](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6507/daaaahwhoosh)
  18 total votes, 6 question votes, 7 answers, 297 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Abolishing slavery](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34564/abolishing-slavery) - [Monty Wild](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/75/monty-wild)
  16 total votes, 4 question votes, 4 answers, 375 views
- [How would a population react to an AI made for the purpose of statewide surveillance using current tech?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34311/how-would-a-population-react-to-an-ai-made-for-the-purpose-of-statewide-surveill) - [Carlos Danger](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17384/carlos-danger)
  16 total votes, 8 question votes, 3 answers, 134 views
- [If a culture split up and its parts were isolated for 750 years, would they then be able to understand each other?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34386/if-a-culture-split-up-and-its-parts-were-isolated-for-750-years-would-they-then) - [CHEESE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17362/cheese)
  16 total votes, 6 question votes, 7 answers, 1034 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Is it possible to have a Transhumanist Theocracy?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33976/is-it-possible-to-have-a-transhumanist-theocracy) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  12 total votes, 5 question votes, 5 answers, 136 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Cultural beliefs, practices, and prejudices of tribes practicing ritual cannibalism](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33711/cultural-beliefs-practices-and-prejudices-of-tribes-practicing-ritual-cannibal) - [dsollen](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/4857/dsollen)
  12 total votes, 5 question votes, 1 answers, 81 views
- [Could a viable interstellar civilization form with this technology?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34462/could-a-viable-interstellar-civilization-form-with-this-technology) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  11 total votes, 5 question votes, 3 answers, 348 views
- [How much could a species benefit from a single child possessing DNA from multiple fathers?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33713/how-much-could-a-species-benefit-from-a-single-child-possessing-dna-from-multipl) - [dsollen](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/4857/dsollen)
  11 total votes, 6 question votes, 3 answers, 75 views
- [How would society react if the existence of a devil was scientifically proven?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34208/how-would-society-react-if-the-existence-of-a-devil-was-scientifically-proven) - [Rob Watts](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6781/rob-watts)
  10 total votes, 6 question votes, 2 answers, 148 views
- [No One Leaves Africa Without His Bow](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33730/no-one-leaves-africa-without-his-bow) - [JohnWDailey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10274/johnwdailey)
  10 total votes, 3 question votes, 2 answers, 132 views
- [How can government function in a world where everybody is a slave?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34276/how-can-government-function-in-a-world-where-everybody-is-a-slave) - [Joe Bloggs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9887/joe-bloggs)
  9 total votes, 3 question votes, 5 answers, 217 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How to implement radical cultural mindset shift?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34635/how-to-implement-radical-cultural-mindset-shift) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  8 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 115 views
- [What would a post-apocalyptic government be like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33912/what-would-a-post-apocalyptic-government-be-like) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  8 total votes, 6 question votes, 6 answers, 317 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [The teleporters stopped deleting the old copies. What happens?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34740/the-teleporters-stopped-deleting-the-old-copies-what-happens) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  7 total votes, 5 question votes, 2 answers, 106 views
- [Is it possible to form new religion with > 1 billion followers today?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34052/is-it-possible-to-form-new-religion-with-1-billion-followers-today) - [Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2071/pavel-janicek)
  7 total votes, 5 question votes, 5 answers, 129 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How would society react to mushroom cities?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-would-society-react-to-mushroom-cities) - [XandarTheZenon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16736/xandarthezenon)
  6 total votes, 3 question votes, 2 answers, 98 views
- [Turning the Baltic Sea into the Baltic Plain](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34492/turning-the-baltic-sea-into-the-baltic-plain) - [JohnWDailey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10274/johnwdailey)
  7 total votes, 2 question votes, 3 answers, 59 views
- [What if androids out-perform humans at interpersonal relationships?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34374/what-if-androids-out-perform-humans-at-interpersonal-relationships) - [JDługosz](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/885/jd%c5%82ugosz)
  5 total votes, 4 question votes, 3 answers, 165 views
- [Effects of Rings; Social effects](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34328/effects-of-rings-social-effects) - [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 116 views
- [How would society see a person who can control time?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34647/how-would-society-see-a-person-who-can-control-time) - [spark](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17543/spark)
  4 total votes, 3 question votes, 4 answers, 165 views
- [What would the effects be of a world where darkness took precedence over light?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34114/what-would-the-effects-be-of-a-world-where-darkness-took-precedence-over-light) - [CHEESE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17362/cheese)
  4 total votes, 3 question votes, 4 answers, 108 views
- [Effects of local solar time with flexible hours](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34135/effects-of-local-solar-time-with-flexible-hours) - [Crissov](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11787/crissov)
  4 total votes, 2 question votes, 3 answers, 65 views
- [Effects of latitudinal time zones with multi-step DST](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34202/effects-of-latitudinal-time-zones-with-multi-step-dst) - [Crissov](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11787/crissov)
  3 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 41 views
- [Life imitating art - slow-motion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33663/life-imitating-art-slow-motion) - [Frostfyre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6986/frostfyre)
  3 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 110 views
- [What mental trait or combination of traits could make a race well suited to warfare?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34691/what-mental-trait-or-combination-of-traits-could-make-a-race-well-suited-to-warf) - [Trismegistus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6894/trismegistus)
  3 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 114 views
- [How would society react to the impending destruction of its planet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34797/how-would-society-react-to-the-impending-destruction-of-its-planet) - [XandarTheZenon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16736/xandarthezenon)
  2 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 93 views
- [Herpes kills, and we have to stop it](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/herpes-kills-and-we-have-to-stop-it) - [downrep_nation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17463/downrep-nation)
  1 total votes, 0 question votes, 1 answers, 93 views
- https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34096/better-synonym-for-retirement - [Neville H](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17376/neville-h)
  0 total votes, 0 question votes, 0 answers, 23 views
- [How important would magic be if people died very soon after starting to use it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34496/how-important-would-magic-be-if-people-died-very-soon-after-starting-to-use-it) - [CHEESE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17362/cheese)
  -1 total votes, -1 question votes, 2 answers, 119 views
  [image: Shot Down (bronze badge): total score of less than 0 on question and answers]
- [How would world looks like if indians doesn't exist at all?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34062/how-would-world-looks-like-if-indians-doesnt-exist-at-all) - [user17358](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17358/user17358)
  -2 total votes, -3 question votes, 1 answers, 63 views
  [image: Shot Down (bronze badge): total score of less than 0 on question and answers]

Comment: Yes! Finally first place! I should deliver some acceptance speech or something...