# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #26: Mythical Creatures

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our 26th topic challenge!

Topic: [mythical-creatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythical-creatures)

Dates: 1 February - 15 February

Proposed by:

[image]

> Myths are always fun to adapt to one's world and entertaining to read about. Lets bring on the mythical-creature questions.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Answer (score 1):

This challenge generated 17 questions and 94 answers, for an average of 5.53 answers per question. A total of 5570 reputation was handed out as a result of this challenge.

#### Posts

- [What does the Minotaur eat?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35499/what-does-the-minotaur-eat) - [Joe Bloggs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9887/joe-bloggs)
  177 total votes, 42 question votes, 11 answers, 7146 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [Help! My Mother-in-law got Mind-Uploaded and now pesters me through the surround system](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35027/help-my-mother-in-law-got-mind-uploaded-and-now-pesters-me-through-the-surround) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  172 total votes, 41 question votes, 19 answers, 7758 views
  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Politically Correct Valkyries: Why do they choose who they choose?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35537/politically-correct-valkyries-why-do-they-choose-who-they-choose) - [Mikey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey)
  75 total votes, 21 question votes, 7 answers, 3039 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Creating a Siren song](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35050/creating-a-siren-song) - [Tim B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b)
  71 total votes, 20 question votes, 7 answers, 2129 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Evolution of giant floating mammals](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34892/evolution-of-giant-floating-mammals) - [AndyD273](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6751/andyd273)
  27 total votes, 10 question votes, 6 answers, 807 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Mountain-sized Machines - How do they Move?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35157/mountain-sized-machines-how-do-they-move) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  19 total votes, 3 question votes, 9 answers, 215 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Lemmings, making the myth the reality](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34922/lemmings-making-the-myth-the-reality) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  17 total votes, 6 question votes, 6 answers, 264 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How would a person who is a snake from the waist down move around?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35282/how-would-a-person-who-is-a-snake-from-the-waist-down-move-around) - [Thomas Jacobs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6908/thomas-jacobs)
  13 total votes, 8 question votes, 2 answers, 168 views
- [On the origins of leprechauns](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35223/on-the-origins-of-leprechauns) - [Philip Rowlands](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7076/philip-rowlands)
  12 total votes, 3 question votes, 3 answers, 112 views
- [How would dragons, griffins, and thunderbirds affect travel and trade?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35370/how-would-dragons-griffins-and-thunderbirds-affect-travel-and-trade) - [XandarTheZenon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16736/xandarthezenon)
  12 total votes, 7 question votes, 4 answers, 109 views
- [If thunderbirds were real, how would it affect shepherds and ranchers?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34980/if-thunderbirds-were-real-how-would-it-affect-shepherds-and-ranchers) - [XandarTheZenon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16736/xandarthezenon)
  10 total votes, 5 question votes, 2 answers, 149 views
- [How do you get an elemental wind animal?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34934/how-do-you-get-an-elemental-wind-animal) - [The Anathema](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/15401/the-anathema)
  9 total votes, 3 question votes, 5 answers, 104 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Building a dragon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35378/building-a-dragon) - [Sam](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17720/sam)
  8 total votes, 5 question votes, 2 answers, 144 views
- [Could Bigfoot have actually existed? How could they be there leaving no trace?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34885/could-bigfoot-have-actually-existed-how-could-they-be-there-leaving-no-trace) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  8 total votes, 4 question votes, 4 answers, 122 views
- [If mountain lions were Griffins, how would it affect other animals?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35095/if-mountain-lions-were-griffins-how-would-it-affect-other-animals) - [XandarTheZenon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16736/xandarthezenon)
  7 total votes, 2 question votes, 3 answers, 89 views
- [What kind of technology would be developed in the process of creating shapeshifters?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35523/what-kind-of-technology-would-be-developed-in-the-process-of-creating-shapeshift) - [Jerenda](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/43/jerenda)
  7 total votes, 4 question votes, 1 answers, 114 views
- [The Evolution of African Wild Dogs who can float](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35752/the-evolution-of-african-wild-dogs-who-can-float) - [Ambarish Sathianathan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8538/ambarish-sathianathan)
  6 total votes, 2 question votes, 3 answers, 119 views