# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #27: History

Tags: discussion, challenge

**Now begins our Twenty Seventh topic challenge!**

Topic: [history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)

Dates: 15 Feb - 29 Feb

Proposed by:

[image]

> While the history of a world isn't always directly relevant to the story, it can add flavor and extra realism to the setting. You can use the history of a world to figure out how it will evolve and actually better understand how it works.
>
> Also, it's fun!

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Answer (score 1):

This challenge generated 6 questions and 26 answers, for an average of 4.33 answers per question. A total of 855 reputation was handed out as a result of this challenge.

#### Posts

- [Is psychohistory a practical leadership tool?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36200/is-psychohistory-a-practical-leadership-tool) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  48 total votes, 14 question votes, 9 answers, 1432 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [Online character generation resources: types of occupation throughout history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36617/online-character-generation-resources-types-of-occupation-throughout-history) - [Monty Wild](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/75/monty-wild)
  26 total votes, 15 question votes, 5 answers, 224 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Methods for creating great people for your world's history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36194/methods-for-creating-great-people-for-your-worlds-history) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  21 total votes, 12 question votes, 5 answers, 401 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Alternative History: If the Hindenburg Incident Never Happened](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36438/alternative-history-if-the-hindenburg-incident-never-happened) - [Mr. Star](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/17268/mr-star)
  7 total votes, 1 question votes, 4 answers, 86 views
- [What if the slave trade occurred at a later date?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36300/what-if-the-slave-trade-occurred-at-a-later-date) - [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
  4 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 74 views
- [What if antibiotics existed in the Middle Ages?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36417/what-if-antibiotics-existed-in-the-middle-ages) - [cassyxoxo](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/18386/cassyxoxo)
  1 total votes, 0 question votes, 1 answers, 53 views