# What shall we do with the history tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

So I was sifting through tags today and what I will refer to as the *history section* seems like a mess to me...ok maybe that is too harsh, but I still think we can make it better. :)

We have:

- [history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)
- [alternate-history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-history)

and then a whole host of era specific tags

- [ancient-history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-history)
- [medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval)
- [renaissance](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renaissance)
- [pre-industrial](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-industrial)
- [industrial-age](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industrial-age)
- [modern-age](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-age)

---

From my perspective, [alternate-history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-history) is good to go and the tag wiki is nice and specific.  We are talking about earth history with some sort of change be it major or minor.

I am also happy with the age/era specific tags, I think those make sense.

**I would propose:**

1. We eliminate the history tag, as it is too broad to be useful in categorization.
2. We add a tag, perhaps [history-creation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-creation), or [history-development](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-development) or something similar for tagging questions related to creating an completely non-earth related history for a fictional world.

And yes I recognize the irony that [history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) is our current topic challenge.

Comment: I find it ironic that your want to replace History with a history-something tag.

Comment: I agree with both proposals. [tag:history] is useless without context, so we should just use the more specific tags. Unless they're trying to create history, which is completely different than asking about history.

Comment: @Vincent Its not so much a replacement as eliminating one and creating a new one to fill a current gap.

Comment: I think you need a solid tag name for "history creation" that is both clear and will be found by anyone looking to create a history. Without that there's not much can be done even if we decide something should be.

Comment: @TimB I agree, any suggestions?

Comment: Nothing springs to mind...

Comment: @TimB Fictional-History?

Answer (score 3):

In no particular order, my thoughts:

1. [history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) is indeed very broad. Adding "history" to the *end* of the tags missing it would ensure that anyone typing the word "history" comes across the more specific tags and would then pick the era-specific tag most appropriate to their question. **Delete**.
2. If we're changing them, I greatly prefer [ancient-history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-history) to [history-ancient](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-ancient), as it makes more sense grammatically and doesn't inhibit any searches.
3. [medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval) has a far broader scope than [medieval-history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval-history). Changing the tags that don't currently specify history to include that word runs the risk of excluding certain questions currently in the tag list. It's not a huge problem, but one we'd want to consider. I present these three questions from the Medieval section as examples of questions that would no longer fit quite as well if the tag changed to specify history:

   - [How can I imprison a wizard who can walk through walls?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12634/how-can-i-imprison-a-wizard-who-can-walk-through-walls) The era it's set in is only peripherally related to the main question.
   - [Possible distance traveled by horse over 6 weeks?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/6411/possible-distance-travelled-by-horse-over-6-weeks) Horses move at the same speed whether in modern or pre-modern times.
   - [Would a common language develop in a fantasy world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29491/would-a-common-language-develop-in-a-fantasy-world) Mostly interested in linguistics, not technology. They just need to be pre-modern (and therefore pre-Internet) to get their desired outcome.
4. Some of these tags are almost never used.

   - [renaissance](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renaissance) has 9 questions. Almost all of them are also tagged as Medieval or would otherwise easily fit into a different tag. Very few are actually Renaissance-specific. Although the Renaissance was really cool, apparently we don't want to build worlds in that time. **Delete**.
   - [pre-industrial](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-industrial) has 3 questions, all of which could either be Medieval or Ancient History. The age described is horribly broad, hence the broadness of the questions within it. **Delete.**
   - [industrial-age](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industrial-age) has 8, but all of them are actually about this specific era, which makes sense because the Industrial Age was a very exciting and rapidly-changing time. There's lot of potential for questions in this era. **Keep.**
5. I like the idea of an [inventing-history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inventing-history) tag of some kind. Alternate history is still clearly about Earth. An inventing history tag would allow people to ask questions about non-Earth-based worlds. **Create**.

Comment: I think you're on to something with the periods here.  We don't really *have* questions about, say, medieval *history*, right?  We have questions about building aspects of worlds in a medieval setting, but they aren't *history* questions and those history questions would be off-topic here.  So, while most of these are about times in Earth history, they aren't about history.

Comment: We shouldn't make decisions to keep or delete based on the number of questions that have already been asked (at least if N > 1 or 2).  It's ok to have seldom-used tags if they are meaningful.  If we think they aren't meaningful then delete, but I wouldn't delete renaissance just yet, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have been thinking about this and I think I have my final recommendation (pending you all slaughtering it with red ink/sheep's blood).  It mainly centers around standardizing the tags and hopefully making use more clear to world builders.

1. Eliminate [history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) it's simply too generic to be useful in categorizing
2. Rename [alternate-history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-history) to [history-alternate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-alternate) to support a new convention (Ill elaborate on the next step)
3. Rename the era specific tags to:

   - [history-ancient](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-ancient)
   - [history-medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-medieval)
   - [history-renaissance](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-renaissance)
   - [history-preindustrial](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-preindustrial)  (we can probably burninate this one?)
   - [history-industrial](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-industrial)
   - [history-modern](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-modern)

Changing the form ensures that anyone typing *history* will come across the more specific versions of the time periods

4. Add [history-fictional](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-fictional) to cover history questions related to fictional/created worlds

---

This change set would require us going through all the history questions and applying the new proper tags, 51 questions at this point in time.

Comment: I'm good with that, as a software person this makes sense to me.

Comment: I don't see any need to move the word history to the front, it makes them grammatically incorrect and gains nothing. Tags aren't alphabetically sorted and typing "hist" will find [tag:alternate-history] just as easily as [tag:history-alternate]

Comment: @TimB Beginning or end is irrelevant I guess. It just makes more sense to me to have the category come before the specific topic and I don't see the need for something without grammar to be grammatically correct, but again, order is irrelevant, I just think it would be helpful to make these more obviously history, which helps ensure people use the correct tags...or use tags correctly.

Comment: We don't really *have* questions about, say, medieval *history*, right?  We have questions about building aspects of worlds in a medieval setting, but they aren't *history* questions and those history questions would be off-topic here.  So, while most of these are about times in Earth history, they aren't about history.

Comment: @MonicaCellio True enough, it would probably make sense if we go with this system for the tag wiki's to say something along the lines of "For questions regarding the *blank* time period or as a setting to illustrate the state of technology, politics, religion etc etc for a question"

Comment: Well, I think there are two different meanings for the tag. There is asking about something that happened during a time period and asking about the time period itself. I don't think we would have enough questions of the 2nd form to justify a separate tag for it though