# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #28: Calendar

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our 28 topic challenge!

Topic: [calendar](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar)
Note that [calendar](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) is a synonym of [time-keeping](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-keeping)

Dates: 29 Feb - 22 Mar

Proposed by:

[image]

> The leap day is close again and won’t be for another 4 years. The Chinese New Year is even closer (8 Feb 2016).
>
> Another world needs another calendar, but how different can and should it be?

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Comment: Had this already ended?

Comment: It should have, but it was somehow decided to have it one one more week until Monday 21st.

Comment: Then there should be a new one today right?

Comment: @TrEs-2b it should have actually started one week ago. And then yesterday. I tend to forget... and I'm not the only one... but now here it is!

Answer (score 2):

This challenge generated 6 questions and 23 answers, for an average of 3.83 answers per question. A total of 1385 reputation was handed out as a result of this challenge.

#### Posts

- [Creating a realistic timekeeping system for a fantasy world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37392/creating-a-realistic-timekeeping-system-for-a-fantasy-world) - [Kit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/18451/kit)
  76 total votes, 19 question votes, 9 answers, 1765 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [How can a floral clock be made accurate enough to replace normal timekeeping?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37655/how-can-a-floral-clock-be-made-accurate-enough-to-replace-normal-timekeeping) - [Tim B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b)
  57 total votes, 15 question votes, 4 answers, 2236 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Measure time with longer days?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38037/measure-time-with-longer-days) - [Eithne](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/14276/eithne)
  11 total votes, 4 question votes, 3 answers, 97 views
  [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [My BIG World Needs More Suns](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38057/my-big-world-needs-more-suns) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  9 total votes, 5 question votes, 2 answers, 197 views
- [Should the Spring Equinox be New Year's Day?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37986/should-the-spring-equinox-be-new-years-day) - [JohnWDailey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10274/johnwdailey)
  5 total votes, 1 question votes, 4 answers, 167 views
- [Reconciling Polar Calendars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37720/reconciling-polar-calendars) - [CAgrippa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/114/cagrippa)
  5 total votes, 5 question votes, 1 answers, 54 views