# Triweekly Topic Challenge #29: Government

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our 29th topic challenge!

Topic: [government](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government)

Dates: 21 March - 11 April

Proposed by:

[image]

> Any significantly advanced society will probably have government in one form or another.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In three weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

Propose new topics here: [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

Comment: I noticed that there's a bit less interest in the challenge these days, so I took it upon myself to set the dates for 3 weeks.

Comment: I just stumbled on this "feature" and may participate, but I'm not sure what to do.  Also, the previous challenge ("Calendar") had a question, whereas this one doesn't.  Is one implied, or am I missing something?

Comment: @J.D.Ray The challenge is to ask questions on the main site using the supplied tag. So if you ask a question using [tag:government], you're part of the challenge. There's no reward, but, well, all we have is Internet points and knowledge anyway.

Comment: 10,000 points to you for a useful answer.

Comment: It's not that I'm not interested in the challenge, rather that I have nothing to ask pertaining to it.

Comment: The last two topics only had 6 questions each, and that, considering that the last one lasted one week more...

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Excellent executive decision.

Comment: I just think that people weren't as excited about these last few challenges. As time goes on, the challenges perceived as interesting and exciting begin to disappear.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to these challenges. Is there an objective or is this just like a "lets drum up interest in this subject" kinda thing?

Comment: @JGaines The original idea was to help promoting less used tags. The "less used" part was partly forgotten. So now, we just have those challenges, when people can try to make a question fitting it. It's partly as an exercise, it helps promotes a variety of subject, etc.

Comment: @JGaines It's a challenge to the community to ask and answer interesting and good questions in that tag. See this for an example of a completed challenge: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2860/fortnightly-topic-challenge-23-santa

Comment: Ok. I think I might have one, but I don't want to put it up half-baked. Hopefully, I can work it into a reasonable, on-topic question before the date gets here.

Answer (score 1):

This challenge generated 22 questions and 101 answers, for an average of 4.59 answers per question. A total of 6140 reputation was handed out as a result of this challenge.

#### Posts

- [Humans can now run 40 mph. How do I keep the stupid people alive?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38590/humans-can-now-run-40-mph-how-do-i-keep-the-stupid-people-alive) - [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
  330 total votes, 54 question votes, 16 answers, 18532 views
  [image: Vote Hunter (gold badge): over 200 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [A society without law enforcement?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38638/a-society-without-law-enforcement) - [Pedro](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13726/pedro)
  71 total votes, 14 question votes, 10 answers, 2939 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [How to explain magic-using kings](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38655/how-to-explain-magic-using-kings) - [Frostfyre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6986/frostfyre)
  69 total votes, 17 question votes, 8 answers, 2438 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [How would the government prepare the country for an acknowledgement of real magic in our world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38855/how-would-the-government-prepare-the-country-for-an-acknowledgement-of-real-magi) - [RedFive](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11195/redfive)
  40 total votes, 14 question votes, 5 answers, 1146 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Medieval politics with fantasy races - Round 2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39116/medieval-politics-with-fantasy-races-round-2) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  21 total votes, 11 question votes, 4 answers, 327 views
- [Could the Internet of Things eventually supplant Democracy?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40038/could-the-internet-of-things-eventually-supplant-democracy) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  20 total votes, 4 question votes, 8 answers, 176 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Ramification of a Government that values children?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38707/ramification-of-a-government-that-values-children) - [Henry Taylor](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3112/henry-taylor)
  16 total votes, 7 question votes, 4 answers, 107 views
- [Could an advanced culture exist without a government?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38682/could-an-advanced-culture-exist-without-a-government) - [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
  15 total votes, 6 question votes, 3 answers, 130 views
- [Which Canadian Provinces/Territories are most likely to rebel?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38706/which-canadian-provinces-territories-are-most-likely-to-rebel) - [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
  15 total votes, 3 question votes, 3 answers, 112 views
- [What sort of legal and penal system might a space colony develop?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39811/what-sort-of-legal-and-penal-system-might-a-space-colony-develop) - [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
  14 total votes, 3 question votes, 4 answers, 188 views
- [Electoral representation in an interstellar democracy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39504/electoral-representation-in-an-interstellar-democracy) - [John Robinson](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13430/john-robinson)
  13 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 123 views
- [Life expectancy of unaging dictators](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39874/life-expectancy-of-unaging-dictators) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  11 total votes, 4 question votes, 3 answers, 158 views
- [Can a super-governmental military body like this work?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38921/can-a-super-governmental-military-body-like-this-work) - [dot_Sp0T](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2746/dot-sp0t)
  10 total votes, 4 question votes, 4 answers, 161 views
- [How to form a kingdom where the king can stay in power for a thousand years?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38924/how-to-form-a-kingdom-where-the-king-can-stay-in-power-for-a-thousand-years) - [XandarTheZenon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16736/xandarthezenon)
  10 total votes, 3 question votes, 4 answers, 261 views
- [Minority Report Precogs. But what they see is set in stone](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38721/minority-report-precogs-but-what-they-see-is-set-in-stone) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  9 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 86 views
- [How might an inter-planetary confederation turn into a highly centralized empire?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39475/how-might-an-inter-planetary-confederation-turn-into-a-highly-centralized-empire) - [DJMethaneMan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6799/djmethaneman)
  9 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 98 views
- [How should the Magic market be regulated?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39875/how-should-the-magic-market-be-regulated) - [SpaceLizard](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9601/spacelizard)
  8 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 114 views
- [How to govern a society of functionally immortal reality-benders?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39379/how-to-govern-a-society-of-functionally-immortal-reality-benders) - [possiblySerious](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16933/possiblyserious)
  7 total votes, 4 question votes, 5 answers, 122 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [The Ice Age Cometh: Global Balance of Power](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40092/the-ice-age-cometh-global-balance-of-power) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 3 answers, 57 views
- https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40065/what-would-the-government-do-if-you-somehow-manage-to-get-your-hands-on-a-very-t - [Yuudai Kurosawa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19918/yuudai-kurosawa)
  0 total votes, 0 question votes, 0 answers, 50 views
- https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39505/government-systems-in-fantasy - [Václav](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19697/v%c3%a1clav)
  -1 total votes, -1 question votes, 4 answers, 99 views
  [image: Shot Down (bronze badge): total score of less than 0 on question and answers]
- [How to form a government in the underworld?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39359/how-to-form-a-government-in-the-underworld) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  -1 total votes, -3 question votes, 2 answers, 87 views
  [image: Shot Down (bronze badge): total score of less than 0 on question and answers]

Comment: Taken 03-21 to 04-18.