# Fortnightly topic challenge #2: Flora

Tags: discussion, challenge

Previously I wrote up [a post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/should-we-have-weekly-topic-challenges) asking if people would like weekly - now fortnightly topic challenges. The answer from the community was a resounding yes.

So today will be the second one. As per some of the suggestions, I'm going to start with tags that have seen a decent amount of activity but still aren't commonly used. For the next two weeks, the tag will be [flora](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flora), as suggested by [Mourdos](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9/mourdos), who wrote:

> Because it hasn't seen much use and plant life is an important aspect of any world.

Remember to use this tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, I'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat). Let's build some new worlds!

Comment: Additionally, there is also a [tag:plants] tag, which is of the same ilk. If you think the two should be synonyms, please [vote](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/plants/synonyms)!

Comment: Shouldn't we be making [tag:flora] the master tag and [tag:plants] the synonym?

Comment: @overactor Maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contest as ended and during these two weeks we had 29 [flora](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flora) questions :

1. [Do different star types produce plants with different properties?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11562/do-different-star-types-produce-plants-with-different-properties)
2. [Alternative absorption spectra for plants](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11547/alternative-absorption-spectra-for-plants)
3. [Humans as pollinators](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11484/humans-as-pollinators)
4. [Alternative atmosphere plantlife](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/alternative-atmosphere-plantlife)
5. [Fluorescent Flora](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11435/fluorescent-flora)
6. [How could a large spherical plant heat air inside to fly?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11336/how-could-a-large-spherical-plant-heat-air-inside-to-fly)
7. [Dangerous salty creature killing the triffids](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/dangerous-salty-creature-killing-the-triffids)
8. [Are flying plants possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11208/are-flying-plants-possible)
9. [Fire Resistant Flora](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11179/fire-resistant-flora)
10. [What could kill all vegetation in an area and then stop it from growing back?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11170/what-could-kill-all-vegetation-in-an-area-and-then-stop-it-from-growing-back)
11. [How long a footbridge could you make from natural materials?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11152/how-long-a-footbridge-could-you-make-from-natural-materials)
12. [Big Green Men... from Earth](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11103/big-green-men-from-earth)
13. [How might Plants produce flames?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11056/how-might-plants-produce-flames)
14. [What properties would make a plant ideal for use on a space ship?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11050/what-properties-would-make-a-plant-ideal-for-use-on-a-space-ship)
15. [That's no Moon: Planet-sized Plants Possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10923/thats-no-moon-planet-sized-plants-possible)
16. [Could plants spread their seed to other planets?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10914/could-plants-spread-their-seed-to-other-planets)
17. [How concentrated would a metal ore need to be to be extractable by a suitable plant?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10884/how-concentrated-would-a-metal-ore-need-to-be-to-be-extractable-by-a-suitable-pl)
18. [Chemoautotrophic Flora!](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/chemoautotrophic-flora)
19. [Power plants — literally](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10853/power-plants-literally)
20. [In a nanotech future, how do you preserve the plants?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10844/in-a-nanotech-future-how-do-you-preserve-the-plants)
21. [What kind of reaction time could a mobile plant have?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10815/what-kind-of-reaction-time-could-a-mobile-plant-have)
22. [How tall can a tree grow?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10793/how-tall-can-a-tree-grow)
23. [Plant-based Armor](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10792/plant-based-armor)
24. [The desert of ore, what would the flora and fauna of it be like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10766/the-desert-of-ore-what-would-the-flora-and-fauna-of-it-be-like)
25. [How could a sentient plant evolve and what conditions would be required for this evolution?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/how-could-a-sentient-plant-evolve-and-what-conditions-would-be-required-for-this)
26. [Could a plant be engineered to live in a vacuum?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10697/could-a-plant-be-engineered-to-live-in-a-vaccuum)
27. [Are there any good uses for infinite grass and potatoes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10692/are-there-any-good-uses-for-infinite-grass-and-potatoes)
28. [Plants to ravage tanks with](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/plants-to-ravage-tanks-with)
29. [How would an intelligent forest control and direct its animal minions?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10669/how-would-an-intelligent-forest-control-and-direct-its-animal-minions)

**Askers**

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/flair/3104.png))</sub>

[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]

**Answers**: We have [148 answers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer%20%5Bflora%5D) considering that the contest ended before the 149th answer was posted.

### [Tag Usage Graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/300992/tag-usage-over-time?TagName=flora#graph)

Comment: hahaha, I was just in the process of writing this up.  At least I hadn't gotten to all the askers yet!  Thanks Vincent.

Comment: @James bad timing but you can still do the answerers. Is there a query or something else to speed things up? There are over 150 answers.

Comment: Do you want to create the new challenge post?

Comment: Yep, working on it now actually.  It'll be up shortly.

Comment: And I think posting answers around here may be excessive...we just have so many!  (That's a good thing...except when you are trying to document them all)

Comment: Bravo. Thanks for writing this up, guys.

Comment: @HDE226868 Can't let you have all the fun.