# Fortnightly topic challenge #12: Humans

Tags: discussion, challenge

Now begins our twelfth topic challenge!

Topic: [humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humans)

Dates: 22 July - 5 August

Proposed by:

[image]

> While worlds can be populated with all sorts of intriguing and fantastical creatures (or robots, or other life forms), I find questions about how a fixed life form we're all most familiar with would fare in other settings to be both interesting and well-grounded (not figuring out a world *and* its inhabitants at the same time).

Remember to use the [humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humans) tag if you're asking a question as part of the challenge.

In two weeks, we'll announce the stats for users who asked and answered questions using the tag. If you have questions, see the original post or ask in chat.

---

**Propose new topics here:** [What should be the subjects of our fortnightly topic challenges?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)

**Previous Challenges**

[Fortnightly topic challenge #11: Religion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/fortnightly-topic-challenge-11-religion)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #10: Time](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/fortnightly-topic-challenge-10-time)

[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #9: Map-Making](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2199/fortnightly-topic-challenge-9-map-making?rq=1)

[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #8: Apocalypse](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/fortnightly-topic-challenge-8-apocalypse)

[Fortnightly Topic Challenge #7: Economy](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/fortnightly-topic-challenge-7-economy)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #6: Evolution](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/fortnightly-topic-challenge-6-evolution)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #5 : City Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/fortnightly-topic-challenge-5-city-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #4: Magic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/fortnightly-topic-challenge-4-magic)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #3: Creature Design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/fortnightly-topic-challenge-3-creature-design)

[Fortnightly topic challenge #2: Flora](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-flora)

Comment: Thanks for getting this up Vincent

Comment: @James Your welcome

Comment: Most of the questions I have myself or have seen others ask so far have been either perilously close to improper for Worldbuilding or not really about humans, like [this one](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/21139/6986). Could we better define how the [tag:humans] tag should be applied to questions and specifically what is on topic for Worldbuilding in regard to it?

Comment: Yeah, could we have a good example question? It seems humans are pretty well "world built" already.

Comment: I'm really enjoying this topic.  Even if the world is just normal humans in a slightly different world, the opportunities for exploration are endlessly fascinating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This challenge generated 36 questions and 136 answers, for an average of 3.78 answers per question.

#### Posts

- [How do you find a mate when everyone looks amazing?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21142/how-do-you-find-a-mate-when-everyone-looks-amazing) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  89 total votes, 11 question votes, 15 answers, 5435 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes]
- [How do you establish identity when people can change their appearance at will?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21204/how-do-you-establish-identity-when-people-can-change-their-appearance-at-will) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  62 total votes, 12 question votes, 11 answers, 1696 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes]
- [Everyone now has two bodies: what do you do?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21759/everyone-now-has-two-bodies-what-do-you-do) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  59 total votes, 22 question votes, 8 answers, 3695 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes]
- [How inhuman can a human be?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21396/how-inhuman-can-a-human-be) - [Frostfyre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6986/frostfyre)
  54 total votes, 22 question votes, 6 answers, 3019 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Repopulating the world from a single couple - what would it really be like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21785/repopulating-the-world-from-a-single-couple-what-would-it-really-be-like) - [chasly from UK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10759/chasly-from-uk)
  41 total votes, 15 question votes, 5 answers, 2193 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Dumbbell planet - how would humans cross the bridge?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21414/dumbbell-planet-how-would-humans-cross-the-bridge) - [chasly from UK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10759/chasly-from-uk)
  34 total votes, 10 question votes, 6 answers, 1990 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What justifications would people use to justify discrimination of people with special powers?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21474/what-justifications-would-people-use-to-justify-discrimination-of-people-with-sp) - [dsollen](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/4857/dsollen)
  31 total votes, 8 question votes, 5 answers, 1249 views
  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Could humans split into two species living on two separate planets?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21465/could-humans-split-into-two-species-living-on-two-separate-planets) - [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
  24 total votes, 6 question votes, 5 answers, 1600 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Society of Kind, Handsome Geniuses = Dystopia?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21292/society-of-kind-handsome-geniuses-dystopia) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  24 total votes, 4 question votes, 10 answers, 496 views
  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [What is the maxiumum depth for an Earth like atmosphere?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21801/what-is-the-maxiumum-depth-for-an-earth-like-atmosphere) - [Josh Belmont](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11251/josh-belmont)
  20 total votes, 9 question votes, 1 answers, 192 views
- [What changes would be needed for humans to live in an ocean?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21468/what-changes-would-be-needed-for-humans-to-live-in-an-ocean) - [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner)
  18 total votes, 5 question votes, 3 answers, 546 views
- [Human rights in space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21065/human-rights-in-space) - [Frostfyre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6986/frostfyre)
  17 total votes, 3 question votes, 4 answers, 240 views
- [How much life could our galaxy support?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21394/how-much-life-could-our-galaxy-support) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  14 total votes, 5 question votes, 4 answers, 429 views
- [How would humans be affected by a 12-hour day?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21521/how-would-humans-be-affected-by-a-12-hour-day) - [Monica Cellio](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/28/monica-cellio)
  13 total votes, 7 question votes, 4 answers, 387 views
- [How To Cook For Forty Humans?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21247/how-to-cook-for-forty-humans) - [Dan Smolinske](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/5002/dan-smolinske)
  11 total votes, 4 question votes, 4 answers, 161 views
- [The limits of human biology: atmospheric tolerances (#1)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21079/the-limits-of-human-biology-atmospheric-tolerances-1) - [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)
  11 total votes, 6 question votes, 1 answers, 153 views
- [What's to stop shapeshifting humans from changing their appearance all the time?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21260/whats-to-stop-shapeshifting-humans-from-changing-their-appearance-all-the-time) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  10 total votes, 2 question votes, 4 answers, 173 views
- [Aliens are evicting us from the earth; how much time should they give us?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21770/aliens-are-evicting-us-from-the-earth-how-much-time-should-they-give-us) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  10 total votes, 4 question votes, 2 answers, 218 views
- [Humans with 360 Degree Vision across IR, Visible, UV and XRay?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21693/humans-with-360-degree-vision-across-ir-visible-uv-and-xray) - [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa)
  8 total votes, 4 question votes, 4 answers, 153 views
- [If everyone had to wear a box over their head - how would society differ?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21484/if-everyone-had-to-wear-a-box-over-their-head-how-would-society-differ) - [chasly from UK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10759/chasly-from-uk)
  8 total votes, 3 question votes, 2 answers, 250 views
- [How would people adapt to a wet world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/how-would-people-adapt-to-a-wet-world) - [Mikey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey)
  8 total votes, 3 question votes, 4 answers, 250 views
- [An alien craft lands on Earth in the stone age and leaves a 'useful' artefact. Did they waste their time?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21698/an-alien-craft-lands-on-earth-in-the-stone-age-and-leaves-a-useful-artefact-d) - [chasly from UK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10759/chasly-from-uk)
  6 total votes, 3 question votes, 3 answers, 183 views
- [Reversal of Human Sexual Dimorphism](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21485/reversal-of-human-sexual-dimorphism) - [Dan Smolinske](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/5002/dan-smolinske)
  6 total votes, 3 question votes, 2 answers, 127 views
- [Are there any side effects if genomic imprinting no longer exists?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21483/are-there-any-side-effects-if-genomic-imprinting-no-longer-exists) - [fairytale](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10658/fairytale)
  5 total votes, 2 question votes, 2 answers, 62 views
- [Narcissus's nemesis](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21188/narcissuss-nemesis) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  4 total votes, 1 question votes, 2 answers, 77 views
- [How would humans adapt their language in response to moving through time at different rates relative each other?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/how-would-humans-adapt-their-language-in-response-to-moving-through-time-at-diff) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  4 total votes, 3 question votes, 1 answers, 93 views
- [How would humans and society react to a superhero existing and saving the earth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21317/how-would-humans-and-society-react-to-a-superhero-existing-and-saving-the-earth) - [PyRulez](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8914/pyrulez)
  4 total votes, 7 question votes, 3 answers, 212 views
- [Is it possible for a half alien and half human (Hybrid) eyes to change color accordingly to moods?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21265/is-it-possible-for-a-half-alien-and-half-human-hybrid-eyes-to-change-color-acc) - [Meesa26](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11200/meesa26)
  4 total votes, 3 question votes, 2 answers, 148 views
- [How should we break the ice?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-should-we-break-the-ice) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  4 total votes, -1 question votes, 2 answers, 132 views
- [Race relations in the land of human shapeshifters](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21364/race-relations-in-the-land-of-human-shapeshifters) - [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green)
  2 total votes, 0 question votes, 2 answers, 75 views
- [How would a human society be different from ours if our feet were also hands?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21748/how-would-a-human-society-be-different-from-ours-if-our-feet-were-hands) - [Joze](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9056/joze)
  2 total votes, 2 question votes, 1 answers, 82 views
- [Narcissus's mirage, Loki master piece](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21611/narcissuss-mirage-loki-master-piece) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  2 total votes, 1 question votes, 1 answers, 101 views
- [Extreme Sport: Fishing](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21198/extreme-sport-fishing) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  1 total votes, 1 question votes, 1 answers, 94 views
- [How to find freshwater?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21615/how-to-find-freshwater) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  1 total votes, 0 question votes, 2 answers, 101 views
- [The Ancestry of Fantasy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21689/the-ancestry-of-fantasy) - [JohnWDailey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10274/johnwdailey)
  1 total votes, 0 question votes, 1 answers, 144 views
- [Fell the phylogenetic tree](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21121/fell-the-phylogenetic-tree) - [user6760](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8400/user6760)
  1 total votes, -1 question votes, 3 answers, 141 views